# Why is echo a shell built in command?

Tags: shell, command-line, shell-builtin

```
$ which echo
echo: shell built-in command.
$ which ls
/bin/ls
$ which cat
/bin/cat
```

Why is echo not an independent utility like `ls`, `ps`, `cat` etc? Why is it shell specific? Any good reasons?

Comment: Bear in mind this is shell-specific. ZSH builds it in, BASH does not.

Comment: @tsv: `echo` most certainly *is* a Bash builtin. In fact, it's a builtin in every major modern shell.

Comment: `which echo` (with MacOS Ventura_13.4):      Under `zsh` returns `echo: shell built-in command`; Under `bash` returns `/bin/echo`. `type echo` (with MacOS Ventura_13.4):      Under `zsh` returns `echo is a shell builtin`; Under `bash` returns `echo is a shell builtin`.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

---

There are two classes of builtins:

1. Some commands have to be built into the shell program itself because they cannot work if they are external.

   `cd` is one such since if it were external, it could only change its own directory; it couldn't affect the current working directory of the shell. (See also: [Why is `cd` not a program?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38808/why-is-cd-not-a-program))
2. The other class of commands are built into the shell purely for efficiency.

   The [`dash`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell) [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) has a section on builtins which mentions `printf`, `echo`, and `test` as examples of commands in this class.

Unix systems have always included separate executables for commands in that second class. These separate executables are still available on every Unixy system I've used, even though they're also built into every shell you're likely to use. ([POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix) actually requires that these executables be present.)

I believe `echo` got built into the shell in AT&T Unix System V Release 3.1. I base that on comparisons of two different editions of manuals for AT&Ts [3B1 series Unix systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3b1). Someone has kindly scanned 1986 editions of these manuals and [put them online](http://www.tenox.tc/docs/); these correspond to the original release of SVR3. You can see that `echo` isn't in the list on page 523 of [*UNIX System V User's Manual, Volume II*](http://www.tenox.tc/docs/att_unixpc_unix_system_v_users_manual_vol_ii_3b1_3.51_1174.pdf), where you'd expect it if the command were built into the shell. In my local paper copy of the SVR3.1 manuals from 1987, `echo` *is* listed in this section of the manual.

I'm pretty sure this isn't a Berkeley [CSRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Systems_Research_Group) innovation that AT&T brought back home. 4.3BSD came out the same year as SVR3, 1986, but if you look at [4.3BSD's sh.1 manpage](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.3BSD-UWisc/man/cat1/sh.1), you see that `echo` is not in the "Special Commands" section's list of built-in commands. If CSRG did this, that leaves us wanting a documented source to prove it.

At this point, you may wonder if `echo` was built into the shell earlier than SVR3.1 and that this fact simply wasn't *documented* until then. The newest pre-SVR3 AT&T Unix source code available to me is in the [PDP-11 System III tarball](ftp://pdp11.org.ru/pub/unix-archive/PDP-11/Distributions/usdl/SysIII/), wherein you will find the Bourne shell source code. You won't find `echo` in the builtin command table, which is in `/usr/src/cmd/sh/msg.c`. Based on the timestamps in that file, that proves that `echo` certainly wasn't in the shell in 1980.

---

#### Trivia

The same directory also contains a file called `builtin.c` which doesn't contain anything on-point for this question, but we do find this interesting comment:

```c
/*      
    builtin commands are those that Bourne did not intend
    to be part of his shell.
    Redirection of i/o, or rather the lack of it, is still a
    problem..
*/
```

Comment: On page 385 of the SysV UM, Vol II you mentioned, there is the builtin `print` command for ksh which is said to behave like `echo`. This command is present in something like AT&T Unix SVR4 2.1 i386 from ISC too. `print "\012"` yields the same result as would echo. Wonder why ksh had print and not echo built-in? Anyways really interesting.

Comment: How many such gems from a few years ago are snuck away waiting to be unearthed by an edit in 2016? +1

Comment: +1. Thanks. Could you provide the sources (references) for the purpose of making a command builtin, for my (systematic) reading/learning?

Comment: I want to find some reference, manual or standard to systematically read or learn. I tried to look it up in the bash reference manual, and POSIX specifications. But I can't find it. I am not sure if I miss them.

Comment: @Tim: As this and other answers here explain, some commands *must* be built into the shell or they cannot do their work. All the others are *purely optional*. That's essentially what my Bourne shell source snippet says above, in fact. Since building such commands into the shell is optional, an authoritative rationale could only give one implementer's opinion.

Answer (score 24):

There is a third reason for some commands to be built-in: They can be used when running external commands is impossible.

Sometimes a system becomes so broken that the `ls` command does not work.  In some cases, an `echo *` will still work.

Another (more important!) example is `kill`: If a system runs out of free PIDs, it is not possible to run `/bin/kill` (because it needs a PID :-), but the built-in `kill` will work.

Btw., `which` is an external command (at least it is not internal in bash), so it cannot list internal commands.  For instance:

```
$ which echo
/bin/echo
$ type -a echo
echo is a shell builtin
echo is /bin/echo
```

Comment: Don't forget that almost all external executables rely on library files.  Sometimes catastrophes happen and those libraries can't be loaded (advice: NEVER issue `ldconfig` unless you know EXACTLY what you are doing).  Also, what if you blow away your /bin, or worse, your /sbin partition, but still have a shell loaded?

Comment: If you run out of PIDs it can be difficult to find out which PID you want to kill. You cannot run a `ps` command, so you would have to find the PIDs manually through `/proc`.

Comment: Although on (at least) CentOS `which` is a bash alias that runs `alias | /usr/bin/which --read-alias ...` so the external `which` _can_ identify aliases (but still not builtins). I can't decide whether to consider this brilliant or perverted.

Comment: At the point that ls command doesn't work anymore, I think you should be mounting the drive as slave instead of boot/master and fixing the file structure that way. I'm not sure how you could fix that extent of system corruption with echo unless you are echo > into a file and that would take a long time to fix.  Granted you could write a bash script that was to fix the system structure.

Answer (score 16):

According to the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#What-is-a-shell_003f), it's about convenience.

> Shells also provide a small set of built-in commands (builtins) implementing functionality impossible or inconvenient to obtain via separate utilities. For example, cd, break, continue, and exec) cannot be implemented outside of the shell because they directly manipulate the shell itself. The history, getopts, kill, or pwd builtins, among others, could be implemented in separate utilities, but they are more convenient to use as builtin commands. All of the shell builtins are described in subsequent sections.

The [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html) has a more detailed explanation:

> "A builtin  is a command contained
>   within the Bash tool set, literally
>   built in. This is either for
>   performance reasons -- builtins
>   execute faster than external commands,
>   which usually require forking off  [1](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#What-is-a-shell_003f)
>   a separate process -- or because a
>   particular builtin needs direct access
>   to the shell internals."

Also note that `echo` does exist as a standalone utility on some systems. Here's what I have on my Darwin system (MacOSX 10.5.8 - Leopard)

```
$ uname -a
Darwin host.foo.org 9.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0: Wed Jul 15 16:55:01 PDT 2009; root:xnu-1228.15.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.17(1)-release (i386-apple-darwin9.0)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ which echo
/bin/echo
```

`echo` is also available as a builtin, but apparently my scripts use /bin/echo on my Mac, and use a Bash builtin on most of my Linux & FreeBSD systems. But that doesn't seem to matter, because the scripts still work fine everywhere.

Comment: Speaking of shell built-ins, you should be using "type" instead of "which".

Comment: Thanks @Teddy. I've started doing that, when I remember. Life is much better thanks to `type`.

Comment: Trying `type echo` under MacOS Ventura_13.4:       both `zsh` and `bash` shells return `echo is a shell builtin`.

Answer (score 7):

To complement bhm's answer, let's say `/bin` was accidentally removed from your `PATH`. You'd want to be able to `echo $PATH` to find that out, right?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the real reason why `echo` should be a shell builtin:

Suppose you have a password in `$PASSWORD`. How do you write it to a file `./password`? Naturally most programmers would write:

```
echo "$PASSWORD" >./password
```

However, if `echo` were not a shell builtin, the password would leak to all users through `ps` information.

Of course, if you want to be clever about it, you can find a way to store a password without `echo`, perhaps exploiting some other shell feature:

```
cat >./password <<EOF
${PASSWORD}
EOF
```

However, having `echo` as a builtin is an important seatbelt as the most obvious way to save a password to a file should work too.

Comment: While a useful side effect I find it highly doubtful that this was the reason.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel: What does back you up? Where is the reference you used to support your answer?

Comment: Well, writing confidential information to files or (via a pipe) to commands is certainly a good reason to have an `echo` builtin. But being able to still evaluate things on an otherwise "fully loaded" system or just performance of scripts are surely equally valid reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Although most shells include a built-in `echo` nowadays, the GNU CoreUtils also include a standalone implementation of it:

```
$ which echo
/bin/echo
$ dpkg -S /bin/echo
coreutils: /bin/echo
```

It sounds like you don't have GNU Coreutils installed (most linux-based desktop & server OS have it installed by default, but embeded linux or other UNIX might use alternative collections of shell utilities instead).

BTW: if you look at [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net/), you'll see that `ls`, `ps` and `cat` are also built-in commands there (or at least can be; it's used for embeded systems and everything not needed can be left out).

Comment: The original poster's tests don't support the hypothesis that `/bin/echo` doesn't exist.  They just show that the builtin takes precedence over any `echo` program in the PATH.