# How do you enter a directory that's name is only a minus?

Tags: bash, cd-command

I downloaded [lessn](http://shauninman.com/archive/2009/08/17/less_n) to my webserver and unzipped it.

It contains a folder named `-`. I assumed I know how to deal with that, but I don't.

I tried `cd -- -`, but that doesn't have the desired effect. Using quotes doesn't seem to affect it either. I put slashes all over the place, to no avail.

What's the proper way to change into this folder?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You want to avoid it from being a parameter, thus we try to prepend something to it. The current directory can be accessed with `.`, thus the subfolder `-` can be accessed alternatively with `./-`.

```
cd ./-
```

---

The reason that `cd -- -` doesn't work is because this is implemented differently if you compare `rm` (see [`man rm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rm))  to `cd` (see [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) or [`man cd`](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/posix/cd)), `cd` has a different interpretation which sees `-` as a parameter (see [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) or [`man cd`](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/posix/cd)).

It should also be noted that `cd` is a shell builtin function, as can be read in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50025/26414):

> `cd` is not an external command - it is a shell builtin function. It runs in the context of the current shell, and not, as external commands do, in a fork/exec'd context as a separate process.

<sup>There is an external `cd` command, but it does something [entirely different](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-binary).</sup>

This explains why the implementation is different, as [Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) and [Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) are two different things.

Let's just suppose you wouldn't believe this, how do we confirm that? Use `which` and `type`.

```
 $ which cd && type cd
which: no cd in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.7.2:/usr/games/bin
cd is a shell builtin
 $ which rm && type rm
/bin/rm
/bin/rm is /bin/rm
```

<sup>See [`man which`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/which) for more information, and [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) or [`man type`](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/posix/type) for `type`</sup>

Comment: No,"--" is implemented in all standard utilities, but is meant to end options. "-" alone is not recognized as an option but as the previous directory.

Comment: Correct solution, but the explanation is wrong. It's completely irrelevant that `cd` is a builtin. The reason `cd -- -` doesn't work is that `-` is an operand, not an option.

Comment: on Mac OS X `cd -- -` will change you to a directory named `-` in the current directory.  FWIW.

Comment: Most comments were reflected in the second part of my post.

Answer (score 24):

A minus (a.k.a. dash) alone is not an option, but an operand (i.e. an argument that isn't an option). Because of this, putting `--` before it has no effect. The dash is an operand in `cd -` and still an operand in `cd -- -`. Like other standard utilities, `cd` treats an operand as an operand regardless of whether there's `--` before it.

The `cd` command assigns a special meaning to the operand `-`. Anything else is a directory to switch to. `cd -- -a` switches to the directory called `-a`, because `-a` is not special as an operand and the `--` prevents `cd` from treating it as an option. This doesn't work for `-` alone which isn't an option.

Putting quotes around `-` isn't going to help, since that would eventually pass the operand `-` anyway.

Your only recourse is therefore to find another way of expressing the same idea, i.e. another name for the same directory. Fortunately, there's an easy one: if you add `./` before a relative file name, it still means the same file. The `./` does make a difference which is irrelevant in our case: `CDPATH` is not consulted when the directory name begins with `/`, `./` or `../`. Thus:

```
cd ./-
```

Another way, since `-` is a directory, is to add a `/` after it. Adding a `/` at the end of a file name ensures that the file is treated as a directory (in particular, the command will operate on the directory itself and not on the symlink if the file is a symbolic link to a directory), but otherwise makes no difference. Thus:

```
cd -- -/
```

Writing `-/` is suggested by the completion code, by the way, but in bash it only actually works with `--` before it, bash doesn't have a special case for `cd -/` (zsh does).

Comment: That blows my mind, I actually tried `cd -- -/`, but due to having run the equivalent of `cd -` right before that, the directory actually did not exist and I interpreted it as another failed attempt.

Answer (score 5):

Qualifying with path is one option.

```
cd ./-
```

Answer (score 2):

These would also work:

```
cd ~/'-'
```

or

```
cd ~/"-"
```

Comment: but only if it happens in home directory

Comment: … and the quotes are unnecessary.