# shell scripting if statement doesn't work

Tags: shell-script

I wrote that script but if I run it I get this output:

```
./autotex: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./autotex: line 7: `            then'
```

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $key = "q"]; do

        dateTex = grep $1.tex| cut -b 43 - 54
        datePdf = grep $1.pdf| cut -b 43 - 54
        if[$dateTex !eq $datePdf]
        then
                pdflatex $1.tex
        fi

        read -t 1 -n 1 key

done
```

Comment: thanks for the help.
but after i changed it i've still the same error

Comment: "_I've changed it_" You've changed what from what to what? Please be precise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are bash tests so picky about whitespace?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/why-are-bash-tests-so-picky-about-whitespace)

Comment: You might find [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net/) quite useful

Answer (score 6):

```
while [ $key = "q"]; do
```

should be

```
while [ $key = "q" ]; do
```

and

```
if[$dateTex !eq $datePdf]
```

should be

```
if [ "$dateTex" != "$datePdf" ]
```

not to mention

```
dateTex = grep $1.tex| cut -b 43 - 54
```

and the other similar line are broken and should be something like:

```
dateTex=$(grep something $1.tex | cut -b 43-54)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Core Problem

Unlike many other programming languages, Bourne shell syntax has certain peculiarities, especially regarding whitespace in certain places. And that's what's messing you up here:

It's important to remember that `[` is a *command*, not a syntax feature (footnote 1), and that `]` is the final *argument* to that command.

In Bourne (and similar/derivative) shell, whitespace (footnote 2) separates commands and their arguments, and `while`/`if`/`until` keywords actually just invoke whatever command comes after those keywords, and act based on the return value.

Another unusual nature of Bourne shell that looks like a problem in your code is variable assignments, which are also specific about whitespace: There must be *no* whitespace between the variable name, the `=` sign, and the thing being assigned.

Also, the output of commands does not automatically go into variables like in most languages: in order to do that, you need to use "command substitution". The new, nestable, and more widely recommended syntax for that is `$(command to run)` (footnote 3).

## Examples In Your Code

So applying the above to your code:

```
while [ $key = "q"]; do
```

..the problem is the `"q"]`. The shell sees that as one argument to the `test`/`[` command: `q]` (the quotes also do nothing here: the shell doesn't have variable types: everything is a string, except in a few contexts, so `q` is already a string - quotes are for escaping special characters). I would fix it like this:

```
while [ "$key" = q ]; do
```

..I also quoted `$key` in order to make sure it's always interpreted correctly (footnote 4). The same problem (and one other) happens here:

```
if[$dateTex !eq $datePdf]
```

..remember that the shell relies on whitespace to tell where one thing ends and another begins (again, footnote 2): if you say `if[$some_var`, it will first replace `$some_var` with `some_text`, getting `if[some_text`, and then it will try to execute a command named `if[some_text`. So first, you want `if` separated by a space from the `[`.

*This* is why your code prints the error that it does: bash expects a `then` only after it sees an `if`, but it never sees an `if`, it sees an `if[$dateTex`, which gets parsed as an entirely different command/token.

Same principle is why you want to separate `[` from `$dateTex`, and `$datePdf` from `]`, with a space.

Finally, `!eq` is not a valid argument/test that the `[` command recognizes: `-eq` interprets the arguments around it as integers (which are still strings as far as the shell is concerned going into the `[` command, whether or not you quote them), and compares them for equality. You had the right idea with `!` as the negation operator, but as with so many other things in the shell, it must be a separate argument to `[`, before the others. So you'd want:

```
if [ ! "$dateTex" -eq "$datePdf" ]
```

..or you can use the shell's negation operator, instead of the `[` command's (again, watch the spacing - it has to be a separate token/field when the shell syntax splits on whitespace):

```
if ! [ "$dateTex" -eq "$datePdf" ]
```

Also, per the other answer: `=` just checks for the two argument strings being the same (as opposed to interpreting the argument strings as integers before comparing them, like `-eq` does), and it also supports a special-case negated `!=` operator to check for two strings being different. If a string comparison is sufficient in your usecase, then you can use one of these instead:

```
if [ "$dateTex" != "$datePdf" ]  # != operator
if [ ! "$dateTex" = "$datePdf" ] # test ! operator with test = operator
if ! [ "$dateTex" = "$datePdf" ] # shell ! operator with test = operator
```

Now onto these lines with variable assignments:

```
dateTex = grep $1.tex| cut -b 43 - 54
datePdf = grep $1.pdf| cut -b 43 - 54
```

First, the way the shell will parse `dateTex = grep $1.tex` is to try to run the command `dateTex` with the arguments `=`, `grep` and one or more arguments depending on what `$1` expands to (again, footnote 4). So, second, you should quote the `$1`. And for the `cut` command, the `-b` option takes the list as one argument, so you want to combine `43-54` into one (no whitespace). Anyway, it would appear you actually wanted to use command substitution, so you want something like this:

```
dateTex=$(grep "$1".tex | cut -b 43-54)
```

..and do the same for the other line. Finally, `grep filename` seems wrong: `grep`'s first argument (besides options) is supposed to be the pattern to search/match for. So as you have it written in your example code, it will read from and search stdin for whatever pattern `"$1".tex` expands to. You likely want to search the file `"$1".tex` for a pattern, so you want `grep pattern "$1".tex` instead.

Having gone over all of this, I suspect that either your actual code is different than what you've posted, or it's printing more error messages than just that one.

## Footnotes

[1] The command is `test`, and `[` is just another name the `test` command can be called with, the only difference being is that it expects `]` to be the last argument when it's called as `]`. Technically, in most implementations it will be a shell builtin, but the syntax rules are the same.

[2] Technically it's whatever is in the `IFS` (Internal Field Separator) variable, but that's usually spaces, tabs, and newlines (with newlines being slightly special for other reasons).

[3] The old, but not nestable syntax is `` `command to run` `` - you'd use this if you wanted your script to run on very old or somewhat not-standard shells, like Solaris 10's `/bin/sh`. Personally, I think this syntax is perfectly fine and I don't think nesting (the only real advantage of the new syntax) is ever necessary in scripts - though I can see how it makes interactive command-line use easier.

[4] When a variable is not quoted, whitespace (or whatever is in `$IFS`, per footnote 1) in a variable is evaluated after the variable is substituted, and "field splittling" is performed on the entire line again. So if `$key` is unset, blank, or just *only* whitespace characters, it will basically "disappear" from the command if it's not quoted. Add if there's a mix, e.g. `$key` contains `abc def`, it'll become two arguments `abc` and `def`. The same principle applies to the entire line with a substitution, so if `$key` contains `abc def` and the command line is `foo$keybar`, the shell splits the string into `fooabc defbar` (run command `fooabc` with one argument `defbar`). None of this happens if the variable is quoted: `"$key"`.