# Getting exception while opening terminal on Fedora 24

Tags: bash, fedora, gnome3, gnome-terminal

I am getting following exception when I am opening terminal. How can I solve this errors:

```
bash: /etc/profile.d/proxy-globalmenu.sh: line 1: syntax error in conditional expression
bash: /etc/profile.d/proxy-globalmenu.sh: line 1: syntax error near `]'
bash: /etc/profile.d/proxy-globalmenu.sh: line 1: `if [[ "$DESKTOP_SESSION" = "cinnamon" ] || ["$DESKTOP_SESSION" = gnome"] && [ -z "$UBUNTU_MENUPROXY" ]]; then'
[snoop@lenovo ~]$
```

Please note that I found this error coming after installing global menu gnome extension.

Comment: See [Why are bash tests so picky about whitespace?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/why-are-bash-tests-so-picky-about-whitespace)

Answer (score 6):

1. It is not exception. It is an error.
2. The file which is failing (`/etc/profile.d/proxy-globalmenu.sh`) is not from Fedora to my understanding.

Find out where does it come from and report back to them. If it was created by you, just fix it by adding a spaces inside of `[]` and add missing quote. From

```
["$DESKTOP_SESSION" = gnome"]
```

to

```
[ "$DESKTOP_SESSION" = "gnome" ]
```

Comment: @mattdm Thanks. Edited. I completely missed that quote missing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all involved, sorry for that error. https://github.com/lestcape/Gnome-Global-AppMenu/commit/10e8494e411db3c4f0ab1f7de6999743d8cabd8e

The Dbus menu infreestructure run inside a session bus and not inside a System bus. So, what this script is doing (in combination witch a line that i add to the /etc/environment file) is controlling all root applications that run out side of the user session as they are lost the menu bar, but the extension can not capture the Dbus menu in that case. With this script we can unset the UBUNTU_MENUPROXY environment variable from all root applications, preventing that they lost his menubar, when they running.