# If - Else statement: determining whether the user is the administrator

Tags: shell-script, root

```
read -p "What is your name?:" ANSWER
if ["$ANSWER" == "root"]
    then
        echo "Hello, administrator"
    else
        echo "Hello, $ANSWER" 
fi
```

If I answer "root" in the console, I assumed to get "Hello, administrator" out of it but I always get the second case. What am I doing wrong? [I also tried different if-conditions such as "$ANSWER" = "myname" and it still didn't work]. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried surrounding bracket with space ?  `["$ANSWER"` ==> `[ "$ANSWER"`

Comment: The `["$ANSWER" == "root"]` _compound list_ after `if` should also give you a "command not found" error (unless you have in your `PATH` an executable file named as `[` + the expansion of `$ANSWER`). Doesn't it? About spaces in shell tests, see, for instance, [Why are bash tests so picky about whitespace?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/why-are-bash-tests-so-picky-about-whitespace).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has syntactic issues.  There must be a space after `[` and in front of `]` in the test:

```sh
read -p "What is your name?:" ANSWER

if [ "$ANSWER" == "root" ]; then
    echo 'Hello, administrator'
else
    printf 'Hello, %s\n' "$ANSWER"
fi
```

Additionally, you may want to use the `id` utility to get the UID of the user.  The root user always has a UID of zero:

```sh
if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'Hello, administrator'
else
    printf 'Hello, %s\n' "$(id -u -n)"
fi
```

`id -u` will return the UID of the current user as a positive integer while `id -u -n` will return the username.  You could also use `$USER` or `$LOGNAME` to print the username, but it's safer to use the UID (number) in comparisons.

The `bash` shell also stores the UID of the current user in `$UID`, so in `bash`, you could write

```sh
if [ "$UID" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'Hello, administrator'
else
    printf 'Hello, %s\n' "$USER"
fi
```

Comment: One last question: why do you use 'printf' instead of 'echo'?

Comment: @Pazu Oh, I use `printf` whenever I output non-constant data. See e.g. [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)