# Script bash, need to send mail if condition

Tags: shell-script, email

I need to send an email only if a condition is reached, but I'm having error running this script:

```
file='/somewhere/here/file.txt'
value=$(cat "$file")
if [$value < 99]; then
     echo "$value" | mailx -s "title"  me@here.com
fi
```

the error I'm getting is this:

```
[line 4: 99]: No such file or directory
```

file rights: 0755

file '/somewhere/here/file.txt' is present

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are bash tests so picky about whitespace?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/why-are-bash-tests-so-picky-about-whitespace)

Comment: @Inian not quite. The `<` is for input redirection, not for comparison, so that won't work either.

Comment: Try https://shellcheck.net/ for these kind of errors.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that each programming language has its own syntax and you really should read the relevant documentation before trying to use a new language. In the shell, `<` doesn't mean "smaller than", it means "take this file as input". To do a numerical comparison, you want `-lt` for "less than".

In addition, you always need spaces around the `[` and `]`. So what you wanted to write is something like:

```
if [ "$value" -lt 99 ]; then
     echo "$value" | mailx -s "title"  me@here.com
fi
```

For more details, please see `help test` and `man bash`.