# Simple bash script with one variable not working

Tags: bash, shell-script, suse

Would you be able to help me with this script? I am learning how to create scripts in bash. It should be working but somehow it is not.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter your name: "
read name
if ["$name"="Marek"]
then
echo -e "Hello Marek!\n"
else
echo "Sorry not you"
fi
```

**Output:**

```
mhudak@nelke:~/practice_before_Exam> ./script2.sh
Please enter your name:
Marek
./script2.sh: line 4: [Marek=Marek]: command not found
Sorry not you
```

```
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (i586)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 1
```

Comment: Use blanks in the `if` statement: `if [ "$name"="Marek" ]`

Comment: https://shellcheck.net/

Comment: you should use spaces around = operator in bash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are bash tests so picky about whitespace?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/why-are-bash-tests-so-picky-about-whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter your name: "
read name
if [ "$name" = "Marek" ]; then
    echo -e "Hello Marek!\n"
else
    echo "Sorry not you"
fi
```