# ipsweep bash script not working (name or service not known)

Tags: bash, ip, output

I coded a bash script for an ip sweeper however it keeps giving me ths "name or service not known" output. Here is the code :

[image: Code]

And here is the output when I run the script :

[image: Output]

Can you please help? I am relitively new to this but eager to learn

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397). Instead, copy and paste the text

Comment: As well, please show us exactly **how** you are running the script - in particular what argument(s) you are passing. FWIW, as posted, it looks like it should throw a "command not found" error because of the lack of whitespace after the `[` - see for example [Why are bash tests so picky about whitespace?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/why-are-bash-tests-so-picky-about-whitespace).

Comment: It looks like you're failing to specify the base of the IP range correctly. You specified "`[10.0.2]`". Do `./pingsweep.sh 10.0.2` instead. Also, read `man ping` and do `sudo ping -c 1 -b 10.0.2.255` to do it all at once.

Comment: The problem is that the bash script reads the input with the brackets. For example, if I put bash .\ipsweep [192.168.1] il reads the  input as [192.168.1] and if i do bash .\ipsweep 192.168.1 it gives me an error message

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy and paste the text so it's readable and testable

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you want.

I replaced `[ "$1" == ]` with `[ -z "$1" ]`, and no more errors.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]
then echo "You forgot an ip address!"
    echo "Syntax ./ipsweep.sh 192.168.1"
else
    for ip in $(seq 1 254)
    do ping -c1 $1.$ip |grep "64 bytes"|cut -d " " -f4 |tr -d ":" |tee -a iplist.txt
done
fi
echo -e "\nComplete. Results can be found in the file iplist.txt"
```

I swapped out the 2nd ping line and replaced it with the **tee** command. It will print on the screen and into the `iplist.txt` file. Not to mention make your script run a lot faster.

Comment: Oh I see what you changed. `seq 1 254` is functionally the same as $(seq 1 254). Though $(seq 1 254) is the newer method.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your response. I'll see if this works

Comment: @TomPps1704 It should work I tested it before I posted it.