# Can I hook into the cd command?

Tags: bash, shell, cd-command

I'm trying to set something up on a server I run, when ever I `cd` into a `public_html` folder 95% of the time there's a few commands I will always run to check certain things.

Is there anyway I can hook into `cd` so if the directory is a `public_html`, it will automatically run the commands for me?

If I can't hook into the `cd` command, are there any other things I could do to achieve the outcome I'm after?

I'm running CentOS 5.8.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could add this function to your `.bashrc` or other startup file (depending on your shell).

```
cd() {      
   if [ "$1" = "public_html" ]; then
      echo "current dir is my dir"
   fi
   builtin cd "$1"
}
```

Comment: Ooh, this looks interesting. I've added this to my .bash_profile, and added a `echo "Testing..."` just above the if, but nothings output. Do I need do something to apply these changes?

Comment: @TomHart If you didn't start a new session then you have to source the file into your current session by `. ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @TomHart it seems there's no `/bin/cd` in my CentOS, so this solution might not going to work

Comment: I've just noticed that now. I found this question which states why http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116955/where-is-cd-located. Still a good solution for system that actually have a /bin/cd though :).

Comment: @TomHart Actually I fixed the function using your link ;)

Comment: That's teamwork :P. I'll be able to get it working great now. Thanks :).

Comment: Does not work if you `cd -P public_html` or `cd ~/public_html` or has unexpected behaviour if you can't `cd` into `public_html`.

Comment: `.bash_profile` is for session settings, not for customising `bash` (for which there's `~/.bashrc`)

Answer (score 18):

With `ksh` or `bash` (or `zsh`):

```
cd() {
  builtin cd "$@" || return
  [ "$OLDPWD" = "$PWD" ] || case $PWD in
      (*/public_html) echo do something
    esac
}
```

With `zsh`:

```
chpwd()
  case $PWD in
    (*/public_html) echo do something
  esac
```

(`chpwd` is a *hook* function that is called whenever the current working directory changes (by way of `cd`, `pushd`, `popd`...)).

Answer (score 9):

**Wrapping `cd`, an existing command, is not recommended.**

A more universal solution would be defining a custom `chpwd` hook in Bash. (According to tags of this question, I assume you're using Bash)

There's not a complete hook system designed in Bash when compared with other modern shells. `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable is used as a hook function, which is equivalent to `precmd` hook in ZSH, `fish_prompt` in Fish. For the time being, ZSH is the only shell I've known that has a `chpwd` hook builtin.

> PROMPT_COMMAND
>
> If set, the value is interpreted as a command to execute before the printing of each primary prompt ($PS1).
>
> https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables

#### `chpwd` Hook in Bash

A trick is provided to setup a `chpwd` equivalent hook in Bash based on `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

```bsh
# create a PROPMT_COMMAND equivalent to store chpwd functions
typeset -g CHPWD_COMMAND=""

_chpwd_hook() {
  shopt -s nullglob

  local f

  # run commands in CHPWD_COMMAND variable on dir change
  if [[ "$PREVPWD" != "$PWD" ]]; then
    local IFS=$';'
    for f in $CHPWD_COMMAND; do
      "$f"
    done
    unset IFS
  fi
  # refresh last working dir record
  export PREVPWD="$PWD"
}

# add `;` after _chpwd_hook if PROMPT_COMMAND is not empty
PROMPT_COMMAND="_chpwd_hook${PROMPT_COMMAND:+;$PROMPT_COMMAND}"
```

Since we're detecting `PWD` change directly, the solution works with `cd`, `pushd`, and `popd`.

**Note**: The main difference between our `chpwd` implementaion in Bash and the `chpwd` in ZSH is, `PROMPT_COMMAND` is not supported in a non-interactive Bash shell.

#### Usage

```bsh
_public_html_action() {
  if [[ $PWD == */public_html ]]; then
    # actions
  fi
}

# append the command into CHPWD_COMMAND
CHPWD_COMMAND="${CHPWD_COMMAND:+$CHPWD_COMMAND;}_public_html_action"
```

Source: [Create chpwd Equivalent Hook in Bash](https://gist.github.com/6cb4e1664574212b125fbfd115fe90a4) from my gist.

For anyone want an answer for ZSH. Use `chpwd` hook in ZSH. **Don't define `chpwd()` function directly.** [More detail here](https://superuser.com/a/1462004/733022).

Answer (score 1):

I am not a bash expert but I would take @UVV's answer and modify it just a little so that it does this:

- instead of checking for `public_html`, I'd just check for some `hook-script` file in the target dir `$1`, say, `cd_hook.sh`.
- if that `hook-script` exists, run it, and move on with the `cd`

This seems more generic because you'd then be able to apply the `cd`-hook to any directory if you so choose, by just adding a `cd_hook.sh` in the said directory.

Comment: It seems generic, but you're introducing a security vulnerability. Someone or something only needs to plant a hook-script in /tmp for instance to make you run any code the next time you cd there. You'd want at least to make sure that the hook-script is owned by you, not a symlink, not writable by anyone other than you, that the directory it's in is only writable by you... See [Keeping history per working directory (cf. per shell session)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204928) for a safer approach.

Comment: Thanks for the security insight @StéphaneChazelas. I have to admit I didn't even think about it.

Comment: I found this question while doing just that: if I `cd` somewhere, check for a `.bashcd` file and run it if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Using powerful zsh approach in bash:

First an easy way to extend bash:

~/.runscripts

```
#load all scripts inside $1 dir

run_scripts()
{
    for script in $1/*; do

        # skip non-executable snippets
        [ -f "$script" ] && [ -x "$script" ] || continue

        # execute $script in the context of the current shell
        . $script
    done
}
```

Include in to .bashrc:

```
. ~/.run_scripts

run_scripts ~/.bashrc.d
```

You can create ~/.bashrc.d/cdhook with:

```
#!/bin/bash

chpwd() {
  : #no action
}

cd() {      
   builtin cd $1
   chpwd $1
}
```

Now is up to you to replace the function:

```
#list files after cd
chpwd() {
  ls -lah --color
}
```