# Change directory based on a pipeline's output

Tags: bash, shell, cd-command, xargs

I want to go to a directory with using filter

For example there is a file named `this-is-awsome`

```
ls | grep this-is-awsome | xargs cd
```

How can I go to a directory with filter?

Comment: [Here is your answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50022/why-cant-i-redirect-a-path-name-output-from-one-command-to-cd) cd is not an external command - it is a shell builtin function. It runs in the context of the current shell, and not, as external commands do, in a fork/exec'd context as a separate process.

Answer (score 9):

[Salton's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140240/change-directory-based-on-a-pipelines-output/140249#comment226779_140240) explains the problem. Here are some solutions:

```
cd "$(ls | grep this)"
```

This is probably not so good, with all the usual caveats about [parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) applying to it.

A slightly better version (assumes GNU `find`):

```
cd "$(find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*this*')"
```

Yet another (maybe even better) solution if you're using Bash:

```
shopt -s nullglob
cd *this*/
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
>>pwd | xclip

>>cd `xclip -o`
```

Comment: Why do you need xclip there?

Comment: Thanks @michabs.   This is the only one that worked in my situation.  I was using output from fzf in the ion (rust) shell.   Problem is that variable expansion blocked fzf's io so xclip provides temporary storage for an output.  My alias looks like

`alias z = 'export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="/usr/bin/fdfind -t d -H -L -E .git -E dosdevices -E p_rsnapshot" && fzf | xclip && cd $(xclip -o)'`

Comment: An alternative might be redirection to a file so that  `fzf | xclip && cd $(xclip -o)` could be replaced by `fzf > tmp__ && cd $(cat tmp__) && rm tmp__`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have one file with "this", just use

```
   cd *this*
```

Comment: 1) This might pick up a file, which is why I have appended a `/` in my glob
2) This will error out if the glob fails to match, which is why I thought `shopt -s nullglob` was necessary.