# On Linux terminals, why doesn't cd.. work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

On Windows/DOS terminals a `cd..` correctly change the directory.

On Linux terminals the dots from the *cd* command have to be separated. I'd like to know how/why is this necessary for the parser to work. If no space is added then the command is not understood.

This works well

```
 cd ..
```

This does not work

```
cd..
```

Probably the regExp or whatever is parsing the commands is not including the dot as a possible character immediately after the command.

Comment: Same as the difference between `my-random-command` and `my-random-command..`

Comment: Many of the answers are wrong about `command` and `cmd`, fundamentally wrong in a few of them. As I wrote in a comment to one, _Unix and Linux_ is really not the place for a full explanation of these programs.  The question is wrong, too, inasmuch as "well" is not the word to use here.  I am on record on the subject elsewhere, as is Rex Conn.  Given that IBM and Microsoft tacitly discouraged this syntax, with the railway diagrams in the OS/2 doco for `cmd` not permitting it, it seems likely that no author of `command`, `cmd`, or a replacement for the same would say "well" here.

Comment: And we wouldn't call them "terminals", either.  They are _command processors_, that use _consoles_ (that name from Win32, but the I/O architecture predating it).  http://jdebp.uk./FGA/tui-console-and-terminal-paradigms.html http://jdebp.uk./FGA/a-command-interpreter-is-not-a-console.html https://superuser.com/a/329479/38062

Answer (score 9):

The normal syntax is `cd ..`. The Windows command interpreter is a bit more flexible and accepts `cd..` as well.

When you use `cd..` the shell tries to find a command or program named exactly `cd..`

To make your `bash` accept the command `cd..` you can define an alias:

```
alias cd..="cd .."
```

Comment: or easier `shopt -s autocd`, and then type `..`

Comment: iirc, windows also lets you do cd... instead of cd ../..   it takes a second to get used to that when making the windows to linux switch.

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/cdhlp.htm says that you can do `cd...` on Win95 and later, so maybe my recollection wasn't completely wrong. I guess I don't know to what versions that applies.

Comment: *The Windows command interpreter is a bit more flexible* and consequently not compatible with POSIX.

Answer (score 6):

There is no real difference.  The Windows CMD shell decided to accommodate the typo, whereas Linux's shells are more strict about separating the command or program (in this case the shell's built-in cd) from the argument.

Comment: How do you know they "decided to accommodate the typo"? How do you know they even considered it a typo to begin with, instead of just deciding to define the command or the parsing in a different way?

Comment: @ilkkachu Whoever `they` are decided to accept `cd..` as a command equivalent to the pre-existing Unix command `cd ..`. Without knowing who the primary actors were we really cannot discern their motives. We do know that a pre-existing command was modified and accepted as valid in the Windows environment.

Comment: @doneal24, well, I think the fact that you had to explicitly mention _Unix command_ is rather relevant here. It's not like DOS was directly based on Unix, and the command line is different enough that I wouldn't assume they had the same goals or definitions as Unixes to begin with. Now, if we looked at how CP/M or such did it, and why, that just might be interesting.

Comment: @ilkkachu Looking at CP/M might not return much help. CP/M 2.2 did not support [subdirectories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M#File_system), hence no need for a `cd` command.

Comment: @doneal24, ah, right.

Comment: This answer is wrong on a fundamental point.  It wasn't a "typo" at all.  IBM/Microsoft's `command`s simply parse things rather differently, and far from being a "typo" the syntax in question was a valid consequence of how it in fact worked.  It was not a derivative of any contemporary Unix shell.

Comment: @JdeBP Contemporary?  Has cd changed in 50 years?  Unix predates any type of DOS by at least a decade.  That's a fact that no spin on this story can change.  It isn't chgdir, or chdr or whatever, but the exact same command used by Unix in 1970 and by TRS-DOS in the late 70's.  I think based on your first sentence you failed to read my posting correctly.  I said they accommodated the typo, not that the code behind 'cd' had a typo.  That means they allow no space between the command and the argument for .. and for \   Try doing cdwindows and you'll see it is different.

Answer (score 4):

#### Why doesn’t `cd..` work in Unix & Linux?

Unix shells treat a lot of non-alphanumeric characters (e.g., `@_+-{}:,./~`)
as if they were letters,
so you could have commands called `a@`, `b_`, `c+`, `d-`, etc. 
So when the shell sees `cd..`, it treats it as a four-letter word,
no different from `cdef` or `cd56`,
and so it looks for a command called `cd..`.<sup>1</sup> 
It doesn’t break it into two words
just because `d` is a letter and **`.`** isn’t
(the way CMD does; see below).
______________
<sup>1</sup> As pointed out [by Bodo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/528975/80216#528982), you can define an alias
(or a shell function (or a shell script)) called `cd..`. 
Of course it’s probably a bad idea to write a shell script called `cd..`
(or `cdanything`),
because a shell script can’t cause the shell that calls it
to change directory.

#### Why does `cd..` work in CMD?

The rules for how CMD parses commands
seem to be complex and not well documented.

- [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Using_the_Windows_command_interpreter) says:

  > The parsing of a command line into a sequence of commands is complex,
  >   and varies subtly from command interpreter to command interpreter.
- [David Deley](http://daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm) says that, in Windows, “Everyone Parses Differently”:

  > You'll get different results if you pass a command line to ShowParams.exe
  >   (written in C/C++), ShowParams.vbs (VBScript), or ShowParams.bat (batch file)…
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/3960947)
  (on Stack Overflow) contains extensive, detailed answers
  to the titular question.

… but (in about an hour’s worth of searching) I couldn’t find anything
that specifically addresses this issue of how CMD determines
*what the command is*
(i.e., what we would call `argv[0]` in a C program in Unix).

I’ve done some testing / experimentation (on Windows 7). 
One pattern I’ve observed is that, after a first tokenization pass
(breaking the command line at spaces
and high-precedence characters like `<`, `>`, `&`, `|`, `,` and `/`),
CMD looks at the first word on the command line,
and breaks it apart at certain other non-alphanumeric characters
(including **`.`**, `+`, `=`, and `\`).

- If the word up to the *first* such non-alphanumeric character
  is a builtin command that doesn’t take arguments,
  then that command is executed. 
  For example, `cls.`, `cls..`, `cls.abc`, `cls.a.b.c`, `cls.exe`, `cls=`, `cls=abc`, `cls+`, `cls+abc`, `cls\`, `cls\abc`, and many more variations,
  act like just plain `cls` and clear the screen. 
  Ditto for `pause`.

  These seem, at first, to be exceptions to the above:

  - `cls/` and `cls/a/b/c` give an error message.
  - `cls/?` gives a help message.
  - `pause/` and `pause/a/b/c` simply pause
    (i.e., they act like just plain `pause`).
  - `pause/?` gives a help message, says “Press any key to continue . . .”,
    but *doesn’t wait for you to press a key.* 
    (This is a bug.)

  But the above are consistent with the idea
  that CMD breaks things into tokens at `/` characters. 
  `cls/` behaves the same as `cls /`, for example.
- `echo` is special case:

  - `echo on` turns the echo on.
  - `echo off` turns the echo off.
  - Just plain `echo` reports the state of the echo flag.
  - But, if `echo` is immediately followed by a non-alphanumeric character
    (like `,`, **`.`** or `/`), then that character is ignored,
    but special processing for the rest of the command gets disabled. 
    So, if you want to print the word “on” or “off”,
    use `echo.on` or `echo.off`,
    and, to print a blank line, use `echo.`. 
    And so `echo..` acts like `echo .` [sic].
- ***TL;DR***
  In other cases, CMD seems to look up to the *last* dot
  (or group of dots),
  and if that substring is a builtin command,
  it interprets it as that builtin command. 
  So `cd..`, `dir..`, `type..\filename.txt` and `copy..\filename newname`
  all act like there was a space before the first dot.

But this works only for builtins;
for example, `calc..` and `find..` get the “… is not recognized
as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.” error. 
So, for some fun examples:

- If you have a program called `abcd.efg.exe`, you can run it by typing `abcd.efg`. 
  But if it’s called `cd.efg.exe`, then `cd.efg` fails,
  because it’s parsed as `cd .efg`. 
  You would have to type `cd.efg.exe`.
- Similarly,
  if you have a subdirectory called `abcd` in the current directory,
  and a program called `efg.exe` in that subdirectory,
  you can run it by typing `abcd\efg`. 
  But if the subdirectory is called `cd`, then `cd\efg` fails,
  because it’s parsed as `cd \efg`. 
  You would have to type `cd\efg.exe`.

Comment: In general, the attempt to interpret `.`,`..` and `\` is rooted in the intent to process windows paths (which might include spaces and could be relative (../path)).

Comment: Possibly the two foremost experts on this, outwith the IBM and Microsoft authors, are Rex Conn, author of 4DOS, and me, author of a replacement CMD for OS/2. M. Conn is famously on record on the subject, and I am on record as favouring what the IBM railway diagrams in the OS/2 doco say. We've both written on the subject over the years. I specifically described some of the quirks, including the one at hand, in the doco that accompanied my CMD. M. Conn has a number of web log entries on the subject. This answer does not really describe things correctly. But _Unix and Linux_ is not the place.

Comment: @JdeBP: Yes, I agree that this question would have made more sense on Super User. I posted this answer because (1) none of the other answers had (IMO) properly addressed the Unix side of the question, (2) none of the other answers had (IMO) come close to getting the CMD side of the question right, (3) the OP asked me to post my observations as an answer, and (4)  Kusalananda also seemed to encourage me to do so.  As I said, I did only about an hour’s worth of concentrated research (to supplement decades of casual observation), so I’m not surprised that you grok the subject better than I.

Comment: And now I’m curious to learn what you and M. Conn have written, but I’m too lazy to use Google.    :-)    Why not provide some links?   And what are ‘‘IBM railway diagrams’’?

Answer (score 4):

> On Linux terminals we have to separate the dots from the cd command. I'd like to know how/why is this necessary for the parser to work.
>
> Probably the regExp or whatever is parsing the commands is not including the dot as a possible character immediately after the command.

Yes, in a sense. Shells (well, at least POSIX ones) treat `.` as a regular character, just like letters and digits. Some other characters have special meanings (when unquoted), like `;`, `<`, `(` etc. Whitespace and some special characters can be used to split the command into words.

Considering that directories and filenames can contain dots (and especially the fact that `..` is a common directory name), it's a good idea for the command line parser to treat the dot as a regular character. Otherwise, how would a command like `../foo.sh some args` work? Would the first part get split between the `o` and the dot? Or already between the dot and the slash?

Allowing a command like `cd..` to be treated like `cd ..` would likely require a bunch of special cases, which would make the implementation awkward and confuse users. It's far simpler to just split at the whitespace, and then take the first word as the command (regardless of if it's a builtin, a function, or an external command). It's not strictly *necessary*, it just seems simpler than the alternative.

Comment: No, not **only** *whitespace works to split command line into words*. Any redirection or control operator (in Posix) or any metacharacter (in ksh, bash, etc) works to delimit a word.

Comment: @Isaac, yeah, you're right. I ignored special characters since most of them will just terminate the command, too (so you don't get any useful words after that). `;` ends the command, `(` causes a syntax error, and I stopped thinking there. Redirections would indeed work, `echo<foo bar` results in the two "arguments" `echo` and `bar` (I can't remember what the first word that ends up as the command name is called.) I edited that, even though it muddies the idea a bit.

Comment: The unstated right answer actually addresses the "regExp or whatever" in the question.  Shells have formal grammars, with lexemes, and their lexing is the fundamental thing here.

Comment: @JdeBP, well, the grammar could be defined so that `cd..` splits into two tokens, in the same way `cd ..` does. But that would seem to imply more complexity in the rules, or special cases to make it work. Anyway, go ahead and edit you feel there's need to mention something more explicitly.

Answer (score -2):

`cd` in Windows is an internal command and you cannot find it as an executable in windows.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DOS_commands) is a list of internal DOS commands.

Whereas `cd` in a Linux system is an actual program which you can find in `/bin`.

```
[root@localhost j]# ls /bin/cd
/bin/cd
```

And it can only take arguments with space, because when you do `cd` or `anycommand` followed by few `args`, the bash looks for the first thing you typed in the $PATH env variable which is probably set to `/usr/bin`, executes the program and feeds anything you typed later as `args`. When you type `cd..` the bash will look exactly for `cd..` under `/usr/bin` and gives you an error as it cannot find such program.

This is a simply better design.

Comment: There is an external command for `cd`, but that's not what you're executing when you run `cd`

Comment: Not all Linuxes have `/bin/cd`/`/usr/bin/cd`, e.g. none of my Debian's do. Even if it does exist, and you run it, it won't do what you want.

Comment: @ilkkachu, what do you mean by "it won't do what you want"?

Comment: Since an external command like `/bin/cd` is run in a separate process, and the current dir is a per-process attribute, running the external `cd` won't change the current dir in the calling shell. The external `cd` can only be used to *check* if a directory could be chdir into.

Comment: _"There is an external command `cd` in windows"_ -- now, that, I suspect is plainly false.

Comment: You’re comparing apples and oranges. In Windows, ``mkdir..\newdirectory`` does work.

Comment: POSIX systems are required to have an external cd command like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50022/why-cant-i-redirect-a-path-name-output-from-one-command-to-cd/50025#50025) but the external command is essentially useless. Once you run `/usr/bin/cd blah`, you still wind up in your starting directory.

Comment: @G-Man, yeah my bad. Removed it.

Comment: @doneal24: Why would POSIX sytems be required to have an external `cd` command?  It makes absolutely no sense since it cannot work.