# How to use external command cd in bash?

Tags: bash, cd-command

I'm trying to use external cd (`/usr/bin/cd`) to jump to parent directory `/usr/bin/cd ..` but it doesn't work (no error message, current directory remains as was). I know this is a builtin bash command and this whole operation is pointless but it's part of school assignment, any ideas how to achieve it?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50025/108618

Comment: I believe all the viable uses of external `cd` are listed in the answers to this question: [What is the point of the `cd` external command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058/73093). They are *extremely* specific.

Comment: Is the point of the exercise to see how many students have read all of the way through the description of the `cd` utility in the _Single UNIX Specification_ and are prepared to come back and challenge the premise of the exercise, doco in hand? (-:

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer myself. Proper usage is:

```
. /usr/bin/cd ..
```

Comment: that only works if `/usr/bin/cd` is implemented as a shell script. It doesn't _have_ to be, though that would be a trivial implementation.