# Does a shell builtin command actually run the program from its path?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-builtin

I was reading the marked answer from here : [What is the difference between a builtin command and one that is not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11454/what-is-the-difference-between-a-builtin-command-and-one-that-is-not)

Here he says :

> A built-in command is simply a command that the shell carries out itself, instead of interpreting it as a request to load and run some other program. This has two main effects. First, it's usually faster, because loading and running a program takes time. Of course, the longer the command takes to run, the less significant the load time is compared to the overall run time

Does it mean that when we run shell builtin commands like `cd` or `echo` , the shell (lets say bash) interprets it differently than running the program `cd` from the path (/usr/bin/cd) which is obtained by using `which cd`.

I had thought that all commands that we execute run the corresponding programs. Seeing that answer has confused me.

If the shell doens't execute the program or file , then why does `which cd` still returns the path of that program ? Doesn't it imply that when we run `echo hi` command , it searches the paths in `PATH` env variable to execute a program by name `echo` ?

Please explain this ....

Comment: First tries builtin, then tries external. `which` is not a shell (bash) command. use `type cd`, or `type echo`, which is a builtin shell (bash) command.

Comment: @Ipor Sircer , do you mean to say that the shell itself comes with the code to execute the builtin programs and thus is faster ?

Comment: We have done this over and over, with https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59171/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38808/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116955/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358622/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354123/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/ .  And that's just the ones with `cd`.  There are yet more with `echo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell knows what utilities are built-ins.

The `bash` shell finds the command using these steps (once alias expansion has been performed):

1. If the command contains no slashes

   1. If the command is a shell function, that function is called.
   2. Otherwise, if it corresponds to a built-in command, that command is used.
   3. Otherwise, the shell searches `$PATH` for an executable with that name and executes it if found.
2. If the command contains slashes, that named file is executed.

This means that the only time that the shell searches for executables in `$PATH` is when the command contains no slashes, is not a shell function and is not a built-in utility.  The `bash` shell furthermore will not do a *physical* search of the directories if the given command has already been hashed (see `help hash` in `bash`).

Comment: Note that in `posix` mode, special builtins take precedence over functions (but you can only declare a function by the same name as a special builtin when _not_ in `posix` mode, so it only applies in things like `export() { x;}; set -o posix; export`)