# Why can Shell builtins not be run with capital letters but other commands can?

Tags: bash, shell, osx, hfs+, case-sensitivity

Why is this?

When I do this

```
CD ~/Desktop
```

It doesn't take me to the Desktop. But this:

```
echo "foo
bar" | GREP bar
```

gives me:

```
bar
```

Comment: Check if `alias GREP` or `which GREP` output anything.

Comment: `which GREP`
`/usr/bin/GREP`

Comment: There you go. You have a command named `GREP`, which is distinct from `grep`. (True, it may just be a hard link or symbolic link to `/usr/bin/grep`, but from the shell's standpoint, it's a separate command.)

Comment: nope, i looked there. Its only with small letters.

I tried which CAT and
which GROPS it

also gives me it.

Comment: Wait: you're on Mac OS X, aren't you? HFS+ is case-preserving by default, which means that if case matters when you *create* a file, but once the file exists, lookups are case-insensitive. That is, `bash` might ask for a file named `GREP`, but the file system considers `grep` a match.

Comment: @chepner OMG. Ant they still call it kind of Unix, do they?...

Comment: Yes, because it is Unix.

Comment: File systems are independent of the operating system. You can use other file systems with Mac OS X, and you can (in theory) use HFS+ with other operating systems. Also, you can make HFS+ case-sensitive; the case-preserving behavior is just the default for historical reasons.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

From your other questions I take it you're using OS X. The default HFS+ filesystem on OS X is case-insensitive: you can't have two files called "abc" and "ABC" in the same directory, and trying to access either name will get to the same file. The same thing can happen under Cygwin, or with case-insensitive filesystems (like FAT32 or [ciopfs](http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/ciopfs/)) anywhere.

Because `grep` is a real executable, it's looked up on the filesystem (in the directories of `PATH`). When your shell looks in `/usr/bin` for either `grep` or `GREP` it will find the `grep` executable.

Shell builtins are *not* looked up on the filesystem: because they're built in, they are accessed through (case-sensitive) string comparisons inside the shell itself.

What you're encountering is an interesting case. While `cd` is a builtin, accessed case-sensitively, `CD` is found as an executable `/usr/bin/cd`. The `cd` executable is pretty useless: because [`cd` affects the current shell execution environment, it is always provided as a shell regular built-in](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html#tag_20_14_16), but there is a `cd` executable [for POSIX's sake](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_06) anyway, which changes directory for itself and then immediately terminates, leaving the surrounding shell where it started.

You can try these out with the [`type` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-type):

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
$ type CD
CD is /usr/bin/CD
```

`type` tells you what the shell will do when you run that command. When you run `cd` you access the builtin, but `CD` finds the executable. For other builtins, the builtin and the executable will be reasonably compatible (try `echo`), but for `cd` that isn't possible.

Comment: good answer. I was about to say cygwin, which would have the same effect.

Comment: @Joshua The OP's problem is solved, but I think for further readers of the question, a cygwin based answer would be at least as useful as the existing one; Maybe you can make this a separate answer, even if short, and deferring to the existing one for details?

Comment: I don't think its necessary, Michael should just edit his answer.

Comment: I've edited in a mention, but I still think Cygwin might deserve its own answer - the behaviour on Windows isn't uniform, and Cygwin tries to compensate in some areas, so if you want to add another answer I'll take that out again.

Comment: It's your choice. I don't think another answer its necessary because this one fully explains it, now that you've also added information about Cygwin. But again, it's your choice.

Comment: Why would posix require a useless command like cd, and why doesn't osx's internal cd not qualify?

Comment: 51 upvotes! I should have just posted an answer, instead of a comment :)

Comment: /usr/bin/cd has a purpose. the syntax is /usr/bin/cd directory program arguments

Comment: It might do that somewhere, but on OSX it doesn't (nor in POSIX). All the odd shell builtins are hard links to the same shell script, which [runs `builtin $0 $@`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cd.1.html). I don't have a FreeBSD machine to hand right now, but I suspect the decision comes from there.

Comment: @John, [there is a purpose](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38819/135943).  Not *much* of one, but you can see it discussed extensively at the link I've provided.