# Why doesn't CD .. throw an error but other incorrect commands do? How to have it give me an error?

Tags: bash, terminal, osx

From my understanding, bash is case sensitive. So `cd ..` would work and `CD ..` wouldn't.

However, inputting `CD ..` doesn't throw any errors (it doesn't do anything). Why is that? If I type an incorrect command such as `ls-a` instead of `ls -a` the terminal throws an error immediately, but for `CD ..` nothing is displayed. In fact, I thought it actually worked until I took a closer look at my directory.

Also, if the error is being suppressed by default, is there a way to have it throw an error?

My biggest concern is that no errors are being thrown, and I am under the false impression my commands are actually working making it harder to debug.

Comment: Ask Bash what it thinks the `CD` command is: `type CD`.

Comment: Here's what I got back: `CD is hashed (/usr/bin/CD)`

Comment: Are you on a Mac? Does typing `cD` work, too?

Comment: Yes, I am. Should I add another tag to clarify? If so which tag?

Comment: No neither `CD` or `cD` work. Neither thrown an error either. They do nothing.

Comment: You can add the `osx` tag. I think there's already a question and answer that's a dup of this.

Comment: Interestingly enough both `LS` and `ls` work, however. So there seems to be both case sensitivity and case insensitivity...

Comment: Ok, I think this is a dup of [Why can Shell builtins not be run with capital letters but other commands can](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164676/why-can-shell-builtins-not-be-run-with-capital-letters-but-other-commands-can). Can you see if the answer there answers your question?

Comment: That's an excellent link, and it actually has the answer to my question--don't think i would've landed upon it using search results. I'll go ahead and mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think your distro has an alias or symlink of it.
This is the normal behavior (Debian):

```
$CD ..
mksh: CD: not found

$ CD ..
bash: CD: command not found
```

Answer (score -1):

That's an Apple bug, your options are;

- re-install MacOS with case-sensitive enabled.
- report the bug to Apple.
- Install Linux