# What is the x command on a Mac?

Tags: bash, osx, x

I typed x into bash, and some weird stuff happened.

If I do:

```
command -v x
```

I get this output:

```
/opt/X11/bin/x
```

looks like something to do with XCode, does anyone know how I could find more info? (There is 'No manual entry for x').

Comment: Quite related: [Why can Shell builtins not be run with capital letters but other commands can?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164676/73093)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/opt/X11/bin/X` (/opt/X11/bin/x) is a symbolic link to `/opt/X11/bin/Xquartz`.

> The XQuartz project is an open-source effort to develop a version of
>   the X.Org X Window System that runs on OS X. Together with supporting
>   libraries and applications, it forms the X11.app that Apple shipped
>   with OS X versions 10.5 through 10.7.

Visit the official site at https://www.xquartz.org

XQuartz supports running X11 apps in OS/X / MacOS, and from 10.8 onwards it is not installed by default anymore ; it has to be installed by the user.

Comment: More precisely, `/opt/X11/bin/` **`X`** is a symlink to `Xquartz`, and HFS+ is case-insensitive by default.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Corrected. Thanks, I knew it is case insensitive, but had no ideia it was that *bad*.  ls  -l x
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ruiribeiro  wheel  7  4 Dec 21:56 x -> Xquartz

Comment: Obligatory Linus rant: https://www.cio.com/article/2868393/linus-torvalds-apples-hfs-is-probably-the-worst-file-system-ever.html

Comment: @MichaelHomer From macOS 10.13, the filesystem is APFS which is also case-insensitive by default.