# Why is my CD command not working on a home-built shell?

Tags: shell, c, cd-command

I have written a very basic shell in C. It reads the input, then runs it using `system(lineCopy);` (lineCopy being a copy of the input). All commands will run fine in it, other than `cd`. When I try to `cd` to a different directory, it simply stays in the current directory. If I try to `cd` to a directory that doesn't exist, it says, as it should `sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /some_nonexistant_directory`. When I try to cd to a directory that DOES exist, however, it reads that command, but then stays in the same directory. The variable in which I store the current PWD is continuesly updating, so it cannot be that. All other commands work perfectly. But why does `cd` not?

Comment: `cd` needs to be [a shell built-in](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html#tag_20_14_16).

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38808/38906

Comment: @MichaelHomer Is there a way of fixing this?

Comment: The answer to your next question is "use the [chdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chdir.html) system call".

Comment: You didn't write a shell at all.  You wrote a C program that [calls a shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html), separately, for every single line of input.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing an environment variable - that will not work either. System inherits the environment and the current working directory. So each system call will inherit the current working directory from its parent.

Comment: OK. Is there something I should replace `system(lineCopy);` with then?

Comment: You cannot - the child does not change the parent in this respect. Anway why write a shell when not going the hole hog

Comment: … or try defining an alias (and using it on the next line).   … or getting a `history` listing.   … or putting a command into the background with `&` and then looking at it with `jobs` or waiting for it with `wait`.  … or setting `umask`.  … or typing `exit` or `logout`.