# why cd function in script doesn't work

Tags: cd-command

I wrote a script for the purpose of changing directory and then scan a file.

```
#!/bin/bash
model_dir=/mypath

function chdir () {
  cd $1
}
chdir ${model_dir}/config
if [[ ! -s *.cfg ]]
then
  echo `date` "configure file does not exist"
  exit 1
fi
```

I don't why my current directory is not changed after I execute this script with `source myscript.sh`.

Comment: why do you even wrap the cd with chdir?

Comment: good question, because I'm going to use it afterwards.

Comment: Are you asking why your current directory isn't changed after the script is done running?

Comment: Yes. That's what I am asking.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38808/why-is-cd-not-a-program

Comment: Is there a way to actually change it, I searched a lot online, fund that define a function is a way, that's why I defined a change dir function. But it doesn't work for my case.

Answer (score 3):

Your script and specially its inner `cd` commands works just fine when called from `bash` with using either the `source` or the equivalent `.` commands.

The main issue is, as already stated in @adonis comment, your shell, after properly changing its directory, will exit unless a file precisely named "*.cfg" does exist, which is very doubtful.

As I guess you want to use *.cfg as a pattern, here is how I would slightly modify your script for it to work as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash # Note that the shebang is useless for a sourced script

model_dir=/mypath

chdir() { # use either function or (), both is a non portable syntax
  cd $1
}

chdir ${model_dir}/config
if [ ! -s *.cfg ]; then # Single brackets here for the shell to expand *.cfg
  echo $(date) "configure file does not exist"
  exit 1  # dubious in a sourced script, it will end the main and only shell interpreter
fi
```

Comment: It did not work for me when using `source` command, which is why I advised using the `.` command, but then again I was in a Cygwin environment at the time, so I can't speak for other operating systems.

Comment: @rubynorails The`source` builtin is strictly equivalent to `.` under `bash`, whether you are running `bash` under `cygwin` or whatever doesn't make a difference.

Comment: That being said, `source` did not work for me. `.` did.  Go figure.  I use `source` all the time in my Cygwin dotfiles, but in this particular instance, I had to use `.` to get the script to function as intended.

Comment: @rubynorails Double check your test case, there is no such bug with cygwin I'm aware of.

Comment: I stand corrected. `source` works just fine. A tip of the hat to you.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `cd` command is executed inside the script and not in your current shell environment.  If you want the script to run in your current shell environment, run it like so:

```
. /path/to/script.sh
```

Output from my own working example of your script with a `pwd` in place of your `if` statement:

```
Jamey@CNU326BXDX ~
$ /usr/local/bin/this.sh
/cygdrive/c/users/jamey/downloads

Jamey@CNU326BXDX ~
$ . /usr/local/bin/this.sh
/cygdrive/c/users/jamey/downloads

Jamey@CNU326BXDX /cygdrive/c/users/jamey/downloads
$
```

Notice the current working directory after the script is run the second time.

Comment: It's not exactly a subshell, just a different process.

Comment: @PSkocik Thank you, I've updated the answer to try and reflect this.

Comment: @PSkocik However, it seems to me that if you are invoking /bin/bash from a current Bash process (such as launching a script), that would be considered a subshell.  So the `cd` would be a process, but it would be launched within the Bash subshell of the script itself, not the parent shell of your current terminal environment.  See [this](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/What_is_a_Subshell%3F).

Comment: It's a subshell if the parent shell forks without execcing. A subshell has (copy-on-write) access to all the variables of the parent shell. A shell created by forking + execcing bash starts afresh in regards to its (nonexported) variables and the process of starting it will take somewhat longer.

Comment: I disagree with the definition it the link. They mention that `$BASH_SUBSHELL` indicates the subshel level, which is correct, however if you do `bash -c "echo $BASH_SUBSHELL"` it'll be 0 not 1, because launching a script does not create a subshell -- it starts a new shell process from scratch.

Comment: @rubynorails The `cd` is not a process, and can not be. It could not change the current directory of the shell, only it's own. It is a "shell builtin".

Comment: ^process^command to make everyone happy.