# Not able to cd into folder in Linux machine. Says file/folder does not exist

Tags: shell, directory, cd-command

I have written a test ksh file to cd into a folder and do a listing. Following is written:

```
`cd "their_file/"`;

`pwd`;

`ls -l`;
```

Gives me following output:

```
./test.ksh: line 2: /home/user/final: Is a directory

./test.ksh: line 3: total: command not found
```

This is my pwd:

/home/user/final

How do I fix this? I guess it is executing cd statement and then exiting from the statement. I am using Fedora machine.

Comment: I have tried both absolute and relative path. None of them is helping.

Comment: Why do you use `? Remove them.

Comment: no need to close, there is confusion about backtick usage.

Comment: Thank you. It worked after removing back quote. I was confused with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The back-ticks around each command in your script will cause the shell to take the output of the command and execute *that* as a command.

Using back-ticks around a command is equivalent of putting the command inside `$( ... )` (this is the preferred syntax for capturing the output of a command).

The error message `/home/user/final: Is a directory` comes from `ksh` trying to execute the result of `pwd` as a command, and likewise, `total: command not found` from trying to execute the result of `ls -l`.

Remove the back-ticks.  Also remove the semi-colons (`;`).  These are only needed if you want to put two commands on the same line:

```
cd dir; pwd
```

Your script should look something like

```
#!/bin/sh

cd "their_file"
pwd
ls -l
```

Note that this will still execute `pwd` and `ls -l` if the `cd` fails.  To exit the script if `cd` fails:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd "their_file" || exit 1
pwd
ls -l
```

This uses the fact that `cd` returns a non-zero *exit status* if it fails.  The `||` (logical *or*) in front of `exit 1` means that the script will go on to execute the `exit` statement if `cd` returns "false" (which in shell scripts is what a non-zero exit status means).

---

The reason you get `/home/user/final: Is a directory` and *not* `/home/user/final/their_file: Is a directory` is because the `cd` is executed in a *sub-shell* (which is what happens when you put it in back-ticks or within `$( ... )`).  Since it's executed in a sub-shell, the actual changing of the working directory is not reflected in the parent shell (your script).

For the same reason, you will notice that when your script has finished executing, you will still be in the same directory as when you invoked the script, and not in the `their_file` directory.

For more on this particular thing, see "[why cd function in script doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233340/why-cd-function-in-script-doesnt-work)" and "[Script to change current directory (cd, pwd)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27139/script-to-change-current-directory-cd-pwd)" (and other similar questions).