# Where does cd command is configured to cd $HOME when no path is specified?

Tags: cd-command

The following commands does the same thing

- `$ cd`
- `$ cd $HOME`
- `$ cd ~`
- `$ cd /home/user`

In three of them, the path is relatively specified. But how or why in the earth the simple `cd` opens the user's home dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented behavior in the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html):

> 2. If no directory operand is given and the HOME environment variable is set to a non-empty value, the cd utility shall behave as if the directory named in the HOME environment variable was specified as the directory operand.

Comment: Oh ok, simple as that... I was trying to `man cd` but `No manual entry for cd`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This feature comes from the [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) which was introduced in [Version 7 Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_7_Unix) in 1979. In that system, `HOME` was documented as [“The default argument (home directory) for the `cd` command”](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/man/man1/sh.1). The Bourne shell's predecessor (the [Thompson shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_shell) just printed an error message if you used `chdir` with no argument (the Bourne shell also shortened the name of the command to `cd`).

I don't have an authoritative source for choosing this, but why not? `cd` with no argument wasn't doing anything useful, and the home directory is one that users often need to come back to. The `~` syntax didn't exist yet, so `cd` was a shortcut for `cd $HOME`.

Linux systems usually don't have man pages for [commands that are only available as shell builtins](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38808/why-is-cd-not-a-program). They are documented in each shell's manual.

Comment: Outstanding your historical explanation. Thank you very much.