# If statement giving "else" response to both cmp results

Tags: shell-script, test

I'm getting unexpected results from the following

```
COMPARE(){
    if [ ! cmp $IPPATH/ip.old $IPPATH/ip.new >/dev/null 2>&1 ]; then
            echo compare going to create
            CREATE
    else
            echo same
    fi
}
```

I'm trying to compare the files, if they're the same, do nothing (i.e. display `same`, but if they're NOT the same then display `compare going to create` and then run the `CREATE` function.

However, I get the same "`same`" result when the file are identical and when they are definitely NOT the same.

these display correctly (as they should):

```
echo `cat $IPPATH/ip.old`
echo `cat $IPPATH/ip.new`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused about operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/confused-about-operators-vs-vs-vs) . The `[` operator accepts a restricted set of conditions, not full shell commands. Aside from that, your code is fine;  just remove the `[` and `]` characters.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I don't know the difference between the operators, but now that I'm aware that there _IS_ a difference, I'm going to be looking it up and learning so that I don't need to ask pointless questions in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `[` character in your `if` test means that you have told the shell to do the sort of evaluation documented in `man test`

It may not match exactly that man page because `[` is builtin to most shells and `ksh`, `bash`, `zsh` etc may implement slightly different functionality.

One thing these don't do, though, is run an *external* command and test the results.

So we can do this another way

eg we can test to see if the output of the `cmp` command is non-blank:

```
if [ -n "$(cmp $IPPATH/ip.old $IPPATH/ip.new)" ]
then
  echo different
else
  echo same
fi
```

Or we can call `cmp` and test the return code, which is closer to your original intent, just without the `[...]` wrapping:

```
if ! cmp $IPPATH/ip.old $IPPATH/ip.new > /dev/null 2>&1
then
  echo different
else
  echo same
fi
```