# Regex to meet Password requirements

Tags: regular-expression

I need a regular expression to meet the criteria for a basic password policy.

1st character is a capital
ends with 2 digits
is 8 characters long

Here is what I have so far.

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\d).{8,}$
```

It meets the criteria i want e.g. `Passwo12` but also matches

```
Passw123 (unacceptable)
Pa234567 (unacceptable)
```

I want it to be restricted to specifically *[capital] [lowercase [a-z] x5] [digit x2]*

Comment: side comment: I hope this is a regex exercise, and not a password policy.

Comment: I do wonder, where ever did you come up with the idea of using the `(?=...)` construct there? Do you know what it does? As a Perl RE, that matches e.g. something like `1xxxxxxX`.

Comment: Yeah its a simple exercise to help me learn regex. Not going into a real world practice otherwise it would be much stronger and more complicated.

I had absolutely no idea what the ((?-...) look ahead construct)) was until i researched it. I copied the above code from another post and altered it to try and make it fit my criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest something like:

```
grep -E '^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]{5}[[:digit:]]{2}$' input
```

or with Bash's `[[ .. ]]` conditional:

```
[[ $pass =~ ^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]{5}[[:digit:]]{2}$ ]] && echo OK
```

Comment: ^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]{5}[[:digit:]]{2}$

Works perfectly thank you for being so quick :)

Comment: @dhag, you're quite right. See e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/170373) if you still feel confused.

Answer (score 0):

Do one test for each criteria, that will make it easier to maintain and to extend.

1. First character is a capital letter:  `^[[:upper:]]`
2. Last two characters are digits:  `[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]$`
3. Length is 8 characters: `^.{8}$`
4. Other characters are lower-case (not explicitly stated): `^.[[:lower:]]*..$`

With `sed` (will only let through passwords matching the above criteria):

```
sed -r \
    -e '/^[[:upper:]]/!d' \
    -e '/[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]$/!d' \
    -e '/^.{8}$/!d' \
    -e '/^.[[:lower:]]*..$/!d'
```

This way you may easily add other criteria or modify the existing ones (more or less) independently of the others.

The `-r` is to allow for the extended regular expression in criteria #3.

---

`sed` thing that will comment on the ways that passwords fail the criteria:

```
sed -r \
    -e '/^[[:upper:]]/!a\
No initial upper-case
' \
    -e '/[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]$/!a\
No trailing digits
' \
    -e '/^.{8}$/!a\
Not 8 characters
' \
    -e '/^.[[:lower:]]*..$/!a\
Not only lower-case middle chars
```

You can't do that if you cram everything into a single regular expression...