# Binary operator expected - quoting question for shell script args

Tags: bash, shell-script, arguments, whitespace

I have a question on how I'm adding arguments when executing a shell script.

I have a simple script which helps me block ip ranges:

*~/block_ip.sh:*

```
if [ ! $3 ]
then
 echo "usage ~/block_ip.sh (DROP/ACCEPT) '0.0.0.0' 'amsterdam'"
 exit 1
fi

echo "adding $3"
sudo iptables -I INPUT -s $2 -j $1 -m comment --comment "$3"
```

---

If I execute this without arguments the output is as expected:

```
~$ ./block_ip.sh
usage ~/block_ip.sh (DROP/ACCEPT) '0.0.0.0' 'amsterdam'
```

---

However the spaces seem to be the cause of the unexpected output of *"binary operator expected"*:

```
~$ ./block_ip.sh DROP '1.0.0.0/8' 'south brisbane qld'
./block_ip.sh: line 1: [: brisbane: binary operator expected
adding south brisbane au
```

But then it adds it despite the unexpected output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source           destination
1    DROP       all  --  1.0.0.0/8        anywhere         /* south brisbane au */
```

---

If this is a quoting issue, how do I form the arguments (without using backslashes to escape the spaces)?  Of course, I expect I may need a change to the script, that is an acceptable solution, too.

Comment: If your goal in testing `$3` is just to be sure that there are three parameters, then you can use the simpler `$#` shell variable, which holds the number of parameters, eg. `if [ $# -ne 3 ]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, that's a quoting issue: `[ ! $3 ]` expands to `[ ! south brisbane qld ]` (four arguments between `[` and `]`). And when it sees four arguments, with the first one a `!`, `[` expects to see something like `[ ! arg1 op arg2 ]` where `op` is a binary operator. (this, again is one of the things  different between `[ .. ]` and `[[ .. ]]`; [see this Q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/confused-about-operators-vs-vs-vs) and [also this Q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/170373))

`brisbane` isn't a valid operator, so it complains and returns 2, which is falsy so the statements inside the `if` are not executed. To tell the difference between an error and a regular failing test, you'd need to explicitly test the return value against 2.

On the other hand, if `$3` is empty, then the test becomes `[ ! ]`, a one-argument test that checks if the only argument is nonempty (it is, it's the one-character string `!`). In that case, it works as intended, though perhaps not for the reason you'd expect.

---

You want `[ ! "$3" ]` or `[ -z "$3" ]` to keep the string as one argument for `[`.

Of course you could also invert the sense of the test, and do the actual work inside the `if`, so that an error in the test would avoid running the main commands. But that would make the code structure a bit more unclear.

Comment: nice - so the reason it is working then is that even though it errors, $3 isn't empty so it passes the ! test and then i have it quoted in the `iptables` command so its expansion to include spaces is handled already - is that right?

Comment: and they'll want to quote the parameters in the iptables line as well

Comment: @WEBjuju, ah yes, I meant to write about that, edited why it works. And yes, you had the quotes in the `iptables` command so there it works fine.

Comment: @ilkkachu gotcha, yes, it seems silly on my end.  somehow i knew it subconsciously but couldn't bring forth the knowledge to a working solution. i have somehow muddled through without knowing this basic tenant until now, but i just seriously leveled up.  much thanks!