# Where is the manpage for [[?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find the man page for `[[` (double-brackets).

Apparently `man test` only documents `test` and `[`.

Are the conditionals for `[[` and `[` are exactly the same?

Comment: I think here it is! https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html

Comment: try `info bash '[['`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `[[` is part of the `bash` grammar and `[` is a command built into the shell, both are documented in the `bash` manual itself.

`[[` is documented under *SHELL GRAMMAR*/*Compound Commands* and also under *CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS* (as is `[`), and `[` is further documented together with the `test` built in command under *SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS*.

The `test` manual that you read with `man test` documents the *external* `test` and `[` commands, probably available as `/usr/bin/test` and `/usr/bin/[` (or possibly under `/bin` depending on what Unix you use).

Related:

- [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111)

Comment: In the manual, easiest would be to use the index. In `info`, use `i`, in HTML, see [there](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Reserved-Word-Index.html#Reserved-Word-Index). In PS/PDF printout, see at the end of the book. Don't use `man` for a manual of this size, there's a reason why it's called a man _page_.

Answer (score 3):

1. Also useful is the `help` builtin.  This will print *22* lines of
   info about `[[`:

   ```
   help [[
   ```
2. The `[` and `[[` are significantly different.  See [What's the
   difference between [ and [[ in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bashhttp://)