# Double-quoting (vs not) variables in [ and [[

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm using [shfmt](https://github.com/mvdan/sh) (a tool to tidy up bash scripts). It has a `-s` (simplify) option that rewrites a line like:

```
if [[ -n "$out" ]]
```

to unquoted version:

```
if [[ -n $out ]]
```

I'm actually curious if unquoting variables is safe for string-based comparisons/tests in `[` and `[[`. In other words, is the tool rewriting the code to be any better?

I feel like there's no harm in the quoted version, it would definitely prevent splitting but I guess `[` and `[[` aren't really susceptible to splitting?

Comment: Related: [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: Yes, it is safe. Quoting from the holy scripture: "`[[ expression ]]` ... Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed  on  the
              words  between  the  `[[`  and  `]]`". I don't know about that tool or whether other simplications it does are safe.

Comment: Especially, `[[ $foo = $bar ]]` and `[[ $foo = "$bar" ]]` are not equivalent; for `foo=abc; bar=a*c` the one will be true, the other false.

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/70524