# Why we can not compare . (dot) as a string value inside the round brackets of if statement?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, string, arithmetic

**Problem**

I have to compare a string "problem1.sh" with itself. It works fine in case of `solution1.sh` *(given below)* where I have used square brackets for comparison. However, it does not work in case of `solution2.sh` *(given below)* where I have used round brackets. It shows the mentioned error *(given below)*.

**What I have tried?**

I have tried to learn the difference between the use of square and round brackets in bash script from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs) and [here](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/conditions-in-bash-scripting-if-statements/). I understand that `((expression))` is used for comparison arithmetic values, not for the string values.

**So, what does create the problem?**

If I remove sub-string ".sh" from the string "problem1.sh" and compare using the same statement `if (("problem1" == "problem1"))`, it works fine. However, when I just add "." in the string, it creates the problem. Even if I remove everything except "." from the string and use the statement `if (("." == "."))`, it shows me error.

**Then, my question**

If the statement `if (("problem1" == "problem1"))` can work fine *(may be, it will work fine for every letter of English alphabet)*, why does "." string create the problem? I mean, Why we can not compare "." using round brackets in if statement of bash script (e.g `if (("." == "."))`) when we can compare letters using the same expression (e.g `if (("findError" == "findError"))`) ?

***solution1.sh***

```
if [ "problem1.sh" == "problem1.sh" ]
then
        printf "Okay"   
fi
```

***solution2.sh***

```
if (( "problem1.sh" == "problem1.sh" ))
then
        printf "Okay"   
fi
```

***Error Message For solution2.sh***

```
./solution2.sh: line 1: ((: problem1.sh == problem1.sh : syntax error:
    invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".sh == problem1.sh ")
```

Comment: Why are you using strings in an arithmetic evaluation (`((...))`)? What is it you want to actually do?

Comment: Why not just use `[[ ]]`? `(( ))` is for artihmetic operations so why do you need that one? You can even do arithmetic operations inside of `[ ]` or `[[ ]]` if you use `-eq`, `lt`, `gt`, `lte`, or `gte`.

Comment: @Nasir Riley, I do not need to use (( )). Rather, I need to know why dot does not work when the letters work?

Comment: @Kusalananda In the description, I have tried my best to clarify my question. If I fail to make understand you, I am extremely sorry for that.

Comment: If you understand that `((...))` is for arithmetic evaluation, then why are you trying to compare strings using this? In your example `problem1` will be taken as a variable's name. If that variable is unset, the value used will be 0 (or possibly empty, one or the other, integer evaluation is weird). When you add `.sh` you introduce nonsense into the expression (`0.sh` (or `.sh`) is not a valid integer expression). I still don't know what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @ Kusalananda Thanks a lot. Now, I understand it. Your explanation made it clear, why we can not use "." in a string.

Comment: If you wish, you may post an answer so that other may get benefit from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a problem in the translation of languages.
In the arithmetic expression language a dot doesn't exist.

You are using a language that can not work inside a "$((…))".

Inside "$((…))" (an arithmetic expression) there could be only numbers (usually integers like `1234`), operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `<<` and yes `==` as equality operator, among others), and variables (one or more letters, numbers (not the first character) and underscores). That's all. There is no concept of **string**.

When you write `problem1` inside an arithmetic expression it is understood in that language as a variable name (with value 0 if not previously defined):

```
$ echo "==$((problem1))=="
==0==

$ problem1=34
$ echo "==$((problem1))=="
==34==
```

It doesn't matter if the text is inside quotes:

```
$ echo "==$(("problem1"))=="
==34==
```

What you are using, the `((…))` is also an Arithmetic Expression which just happens to have no output. It just sets the **exit status** (and, as in C, it is true if the result of the expression is **not 0**).

```
$ (( 1 + 1 ))  ; echo "$?"
0
$ (( 0 ))      ; echo "$?"
1
$ (( 1 - 10 )) ; echo "$?"
0
```

But an arithmetic expression doesn't understand what a dot is, neither as an operator nor as a variable name, so, it generates a syntax error:

```
$ echo "$(( 1.3 ))"
bash: 1.3 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".3 ")
```

The same also apply to a variable name (`problem1`) followed by a dot and followed by another variable name (`sh`).

```
$ echo "$((problem1.sh))"
bash: problem1.sh: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".sh")
```

If the operator were a `+` instead of a dot, the expression would work:

```
$ echo "$((problem1+sh))"
34
```

If `problem1` has been set to 34 (as above).

So, the only way to compare **strings** is to use `[[…]]`:

```
$ [[ problem1.sh == problem1.sh ]] && echo YES
YES
```

(not quoting the right side of `==` in this particular case as there is no variable expansion and the string has no glob characters, but in general, do quote the string on the right side of the `==`).

Or, similar to what you wrote:

```
if       [[ "problem1.sh" == "problem1.sh" ]]
then     printf "Okay"   
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, (( == )) compares two numeric values. But inside those (( )), for convenience, you can also just write variable names -- you don't have to say $VAR, just VAR.

Also note, the error message does not contain the quotes. I'm mildly surprised at that. Actually, no -- the parser inspects it for substitutions, then passes the word with quotes removed.

Nevertheless, I believe the parser is quite happy to accept problem1 as a variable name, until it hits the .; so it reports the text it can't understand, starting at ".sh".