# sh (not bash) does not recognize single [ or double [[ brackets?

Tags: shell, test

I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# note: we must use sh instead of bash, it's more cross-platform

set -e;

if [[ "$skip_postinstall" == "yes" ]]; then   # TODO rename 'skip_postinstall' to something more specific
    echo "skipping postinstall routine.";
    exit 0;
fi

export FORCE_COLOR=1;
export skip_postinstall="yes";   # TODO rename 'skip_postinstall' to something more specific

mkdir -p "$HOME/.oresoftware/bin" || {
  echo "Could not create .oresoftware dir in user home.";
  exit 1;
}

(
  echo 'Installing run-tsc-if on your system.';
  curl  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -s -S -o- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oresoftware/run-tsc-if/master/install.sh' | bash || {
     echo 'Could not install run-tsc-if on your system. That is a problem.';
     exit 1;
  }
) 2> /dev/null


if [[ "$(uname -s)" != "Darwin" ]]; then
   exit 0;
fi

if [[ ! -f "$HOME/.oresoftware/bin/realpath" ]]; then
  (
    curl --silent -o- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oresoftware/realpath/master/assets/install.sh' | bash || {
       echo "Could not install realpath on your system.";
       exit 1;
    }
  )
fi

# the end of the postinstall script
```

when I run it I get:

```
./assets/postinstall.sh: 7: ./assets/postinstall.sh: [[: not found
Installing run-tsc-if on your system.

 => Installing 'run-tsc-if' on your system.
 => run-tsc-if download/installation succeeded.

./assets/postinstall.sh: 29: ./assets/postinstall.sh: [[: not found
./assets/postinstall.sh: 33: ./assets/postinstall.sh: [[: not found
```

but if I replace the double [[ brackets with single brackets, I get:

```
./postinstall.sh: 7: [: unexpected operator
```

which just comes from:

```
if [ "$skip_postinstall" == "yes" ]; then  
    echo "skipping postinstall routine.";
    exit 0;
fi
```

umm what do I do? I tried using `test` instead of `[` and `[[` and that didn't work either.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/117549

Comment: Copy/paste your script with `[[`s into http://shellcheck.net and note the error messages. Now replace the `[[`s by `[`s. You'll find it pretty clear what and where the problem is and you can click on the error codes for more info :-).

Comment: thanks Ed thatll do much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because sh cannot handle == comparison, so it needs to be:

```
if [ "$skip_postinstall" = "yes" ]; then  
    echo "skipping postinstall routine.";
    exit 0;
fi
```

not this

```
if [ "$skip_postinstall" == "yes" ]; then  
    echo "skipping postinstall routine.";
    exit 0;
fi
```

crikey

Answer (score 3):

`[[` is the "extended test" originating from ksh and also supported by bash/zsh so it *should not* recognize them.  Additionally the `==` operator is not POSIX, `=` is the shell test operator for string comparison.

These are two very common [bashisms](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism).

Comment: shame it doesn't say `== not recognized` instead of `[ not recognized` :( but if figured it out

Comment: @AlexanderMills: it does say "unexpected operator"

Comment: @AlexanderMills, If that's dash, it does say `dash: 1: [: foo: unexpected operator` for `[ foo == bar ]`, so it seems it would print the first argument, but I guess it's empty in your case. I don't know why it works like that, with the three-argument test, the middle one is the important one.

Comment: not really, `[[` is a `ksh88` feature. It is intentionally not in POSIX.