# What is the difference between $(CC) and $CC?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to use yocto poky environment. I did the following:

```
#source environment-setup-cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
```

Now, if I try to compile the program using:

```
#$(CC) hello.c -o hello.elf
```

it throws me error since `$(CC)` isn't defined.

However, if I do `$CC` it works. I am confused on what is the fundamental difference between $(CC) and `$CC`?

Comment: You may be confusing Makefile syntax with shell syntax - in any case, you may find this helpful [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306141/65304)

Comment: In a makefile, both $(CC) and ${CC} work, in the shell, only ${CC} works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've seen `$(CC)` in a Makefile where it serves as an expansion of the variable `CC`, which normally holds the name of the C compiler.  The `$(...)` syntax for variable expansions in Makefiles is used whenever a variable with a multi-character name is expanded, as `$CC` would otherwise expand to the value of the variable `C` followed by a literal `C` (`$CC` would in effect be the same as `$(C)C` in a Makefile).

In the shell though, due to having a different syntax, `$(CC)` is a command substitution that would be replaced by the output of running the command `CC`.  If there is no such command on your system, you would see a "command not found" error.

It's also possible that you've mistaken `$(CC)` for `${CC}` which, in the shell, is equivalent to `$CC` under most circumstances.  The curly braces are only needed if the variable's expansion is followed *immediately* by some other string that would otherwise be interpreted as part of the variable's name. An example of the difference may be seen in `"$CC_hello"` (expands the variable called `CC_hello`) and `"${CC}_hello"` (expands the variable `CC` and appends the string `_hello` to its value). In all other circumstances, `${CC}` is equivalent to `$CC`.  Note that using curly braces is *not* quoting the expansion, i.e. `${CC}` is *not* the same as `"$CC"`.

If have a shell or environment variable holding the name of the compiler that you're using for compiling C code, and you want to use that variable on the command line, then use `"$CC"`, or just `$CC` if the variable's value does not contain spaces or shell globbing characters.

```
$CC -o hello.elf hello.c
```

Comment: Of course, by its *nature* you don't know if `$CC` will have spaces in its expansion, so you virtually always want `"$CC"`.

Answer (score 4):

The two are not equivalent.  In a line that contains `$(foo)`, the `$(foo)` is replaced with the output of the command `foo`.  For example:

```
$ echo "hello $(echo world)"
hello world
```

In a line that contains `$foo`, the `$foo` is replaced with the value of the variable named `foo`.  For example:

```
$ foo=world
$ echo "hello $foo"
hello world
```

Comment: They may have seen `$(CC)` in a Makefile...

Comment: Not necessarily *environment* variable.

Answer (score 2):

This answer does not consider makefile syntax.

`"$(CC)"` is the output of the command `CC`.

`"$CC"` is the value of the variable `CC`.

This should make the difference clear:

```
$ CC=ls
$ echo $(CC)
CC: command not found
$ echo $CC
ls
```

and

```
$ echo $($CC)
bin   cdrom  dev  home        initrd.img.old  lost+found  mnt  proc  run ...
```