# If statement [ or [[ or ( or ((?

Tags: shell-script

As a very confused newbie, what's up with the **IF** statement and **[ ], [[ ]], ( ), (( ))**

why is

```
if [ $jengnr -eq 1 ]; then
```

correct, but here it's double:

```
if [[ -f "$jdir$object.eng.dat" ]]; then
```

and then I read that a nested if inside an if should be (( )) (not my code)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Nested if statements
if [ $1 -gt 100 ]
then
echo Hey that\'s a large number.
if (( $1 % 2 == 0 ))
then
echo And is also an even number.
fi
fi
```

but I used [[ ]] in an if statement that was inside an if [[ ]] statement, and that worked to?

Can somebody please explain what, who and why there are 4 different if?

.. and when to use them correctly?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/315749)

Comment: are you talking about `bash`?  ... run `man bash` in a console

Comment: See [What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

Comment: thx for the quick redirection, didn't find the answer when I was searching for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `[`

This is the shell test command (sometimes also a builtin) and is a portable method to perform shell tests.

## `[[`

This is often referred to as the "extended test", it is supported mostly only by ksh and bash and allows more features than the shell test but is not as portable

## `(`

This is not a test command at all, single parenthesis will create a subshell.  if statements simply evaluate the return code from the command following them so using `if ( command ); then` would work but it would simply be evaluating the return of the subshell.

## `((`

This allows for shell arithmetic which can be used to in conjunction with `if` when you are testing on arithmetic related conditions.

---

Additionally note that there is no such rule for nested if statements, you can use any combination of these methods at any level of nesting.

Comment: so with other words, if I'm working is bash, it's better to use [[ ]] instead of [ ], since this is the "old" way, and [[ ]] is more and better?

Comment: @JoBe: not necessarily.  Often in shell scripting portability is strongly desired so if `[` works for you there is nothing wrong with using it.

Comment: I c, but if I'm writing one for only me, to be run on only one computer, with bash, wouldn't using [[ ]] everywhere eliminate any mistakes I might do when writing [ ] and trying to test something that's not supported in the [ ] test?