# Trouble getting bash tests working in .xsessionrc that work fine on command line

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I've clearly become incapable of solving what seemed to me a simple rtfm issue. This line works fine on the command line (both zsh and bash):-

```
[[ -f ${HOME}/.xsessionrc.local ]] && . ${HOME}/.xsessionrc.local
```

When I put it in my .xsessionrc (shebanged with bash) it doesn't.

Am I misunderstanding that double square brackets should work? As I say, they do on the bash command line.

Both these lines work (when uncommented):-

It's not so much that I need that first to work as clearly I can use one of the other forms, but why doesn't it work "in script" but does when used directly from the command line? Some nuance about how XSession sources .xsessionrc?

```
  # F=${HOME}/.xsessionrc.local;[ -f $F ] && . $F
  # [ -f ~/.xsessionrc.local ] && .  ${HOME}/.xsessionrc.local
```

Thanks for your patience. I'm blind to it now. I've spent hours on this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
[ -f "$HOME/.xsessionrc.local" ] && . "$HOME/.xsessionrc.local"
```

i.e., single square brackets and quoting the pathnames of the file.

The double square brackets is a non-standard test syntax in the `bash` (and other) shells.  It is not clear that  it is actually `bash` that is  reading your file, and it may well be `/bin/sh` which may not understand the double square bracket syntax for tests.

See also:

- [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

Comment: Yes, I had the single brackets working. Quick Q. does the shebang not force the issue though in my .xsessionrc file? [[]] is documented as a bash friendly built in and it does indeed work from both zsh and bash command lines. https://stackoverflow.com/a/669461/37370 . In other words [[ is standard for remotely newer bash or am I misreading?

Comment: @RichieHH Yes, `bash` and `zsh` and others can use `[[ ... ]]`.  `/bin/sh` can not. The shell that is executing your `.xsessionrc` file is not your login script but whatever shell the graphical login session manager (GDM?) is picking, most likely `/bin/sh` since it's available on any Unix system.  The `/bin/sh` shell may not, as I said, understand the double square bracket test syntax.

Comment: @RichieHH A `#!` line would not matter if the file is sourced, or executed with an explicit interpreter.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. Confusing to a degree but most evolved SW is ;) I'm not using a GDM btw, but startx from bash in a login terminal, which -> xinitrc > X11/Xsessionrc -> .xsessionc.