# What does `]` stands for in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

In `if [ ... ]`, I know that `[` stands for `test`. What does `]` stands for?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408003/70524: "`]` is just an argument of `[` that prevents further arguments from being used."

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate, it's specifically about the `]`; a couple of the answers on that other question mention in passing (correctly) that `]` is just an argument to the `[` command, but they (incorrectly) say it tells `[` where the end of the expression is. `]` can occur within the expression, but it must (also) occur at the end (i.e. as the last argument to `[`). Try `[ foo = bar` or `/usr/bin/[ foo = bar`, and you'll get an error message *from the `[` command* that "]" is missing.

Comment: @muru As I said, that's wrong. Try `if [ ] = foo ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi` vs `if [ ] = ] ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi`. In both cases, `]` occurs as the first argument to `[`, but it does not prevent the other arguments from being parsed as part of the expression.

Comment: @GordonDavisson then please update those answers.

Comment: @muru I've left comments for the authors of those answers. However, I'd still argue that this is a different question that happens to overlap -- slightly -- with some of the answers to the other question.

Comment: “I know that `[` stands for `test`” — it doesn’t, `[` and `test` are [slightly different](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) (in particular, `[` requires `]`, `test` doesn’t, and will fail with an extra `]`). On my system they aren’t even the same binary.