# How to check a substring in Bash with single square bracket "["?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to detect if the input argument contains some sub-string.

I tried below scripts:

#1:

```
#!/bin/sh

if  [ $1 = *abc* ]
then
    echo contains abc
else
    echo not contains abc
fi
```

#2:

```
if  [ "$1" = "*abc*" ]
then
    echo contains abc
else
    echo not contains abc
fi
```

#3:

```
if  [ "$1" = *"abc"* ]
then
    echo contains abc
else
    echo not contains abc
fi
```

All #1 ~ #3 don't work.

But below ones with `[[` can easily work:

#4:

```
if  [[ $1 = *"abc"* ]]
then
    echo contains abc
else
    echo not contains abc
fi
```

#5:

```
if  [[ $1 = *abc* ]]
then
    echo contains abc
else
    echo not contains abc
fi
```

So is it possible to make the single `[` work?

### ADD 1 - 10:55 AM 9/21/2021

Just found a VERY USEFUL thread:

[What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs)

Comment: So, you tagged this with [[tag:bash]], and ask if it's possible to make the single `[` work with the pattern. Counter-question: is there a reason to want to use `[` in particular, when Bash supports `[[` which does exactly what you want?

Answer (score 0):

`[[` is [a shell builtin](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS). It is a more versatile version of `[`, which is an executable in `/usr/bin` (see the [documentation and `man` page of `test`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/test-invocation.html#test-invocation) for further details).

`[` is more portable, while `[[` is more versatile, and it's generally the variant you should use.

```sh
if  [[ $1 == *"abc"* ]]; then
    echo "substring present"
else
    echo "substring not present"
fi
```

---

Another good way of testing for substring is to use the regex operator:

```sh
if [[ "$1" =~ .*"abc".* ]]; then
    echo "contains"
else
    echo "doesn't contain"
fi
```

Note that the expression after `=~` is a *regular expression* and not just globbing.

---

Yet another way of checking substrings is to use `case`:

```sh
case $1 in
    *"abs"*)
        echo "substring present"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "substring not present"
        ;;
esac
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `grep`, as CPH explained in his post. However you need to make sure to use a [here-doc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```sh
if grep -q "abc" <<< "$STR"; then
    echo "substring present"
else
    echo "substring not present"
fi
```

Comment: I remember `[[` is a keyword, which is syntax concept, while a `builtin` is some built-in command. Correct me if I am wrong because I am new to bash.

Comment: @smwikipedia it is a command, invoking `test` just like `[`, except it's part of bash. Run `man test` to get a man page for the "normal" `[`.

Comment: I just tried `type [[`. It gives me `[[ is a shell keyword`. And I tried `type [`. It gives me `[ is a shell builtin`.  I tried in CygWin.

Comment: @smwikipedia you can also do `help [[` to get a quick synopsis from within bash.

Comment: @smwikipedia that's because the modern bash abstracts a bunch of "standard" POSIX commands like `true`, `false`, and a bunch others, like `[`. Technically there's little difference, as it doesn't work like an operator. Operators for instance are things like '&' to run something in the background, or `<` and `>` and `|` to re-route STDOUT and STDIN (and STDERR).

Answer (score -2):

Is there a reason you want to use single brackets?

A simpler way would be something like this:

```
if echo "$1" | grep 'abc' > /dev/null; then
    # Do if true substring found
else
    # substring not found
fi
```

If you're not familiar with the `grep` command, it just searches a string for the parameter/value you give. You can ignore case if you want using the `-i` flag, the above will look specifically for a lowercase 'abc' in your parameter '$1'

Comment: Just curious. It seems `[[` is an enhancement comes after `[`. Just wonder how people do that before `[[`.

Comment: Ahh I see. I'll give my understanding here:  `[[ ]]` are used for operators (greater than, less than, etc). `[ ]` is used for string comparisons. I just noticed this though, what you have in your question may work (not 100% sure though). You just need to change `=` to `==` (I believe)

Comment: The only hesitation I have on it working is the wildcard `*`. I don't know if that will be accepted as proper syntax

Comment: I tried `if  [ "$1" == *abc* ]`, still doesn' work. I will try some more.

Comment: the only thing that MAY work would be `*"abc"*`, but even then I doubt it. doing `*abc*` will not compile, and will probably give an error similar to "*abc* is not a command" or something along those lines.