# What is the difference between the commands builtin cd and cd?

Tags: bash, shell, cd-command

I encountered a Linux command, `builtin cd`.

What is the difference between the commands `builtin cd` and `cd`?

In fact, I made some researches about the difference, but I could not find a remarkable and significant explanation about this.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38808/117549

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15691977/974555

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `cd` command is a built-in, so normally `builtin cd` will do the same thing as `cd`. But there is a difference if `cd` is redefined as a function or alias, in which case `cd` will call the function/alias but `builtin cd` will still change the directory (in other words, will keep the built-in accessible even if clobbered by a function.)

For example:

```
user:~$ cd () { echo "I won't let you change directories"; }
user:~$ cd mysubdir
I won't let you change directories
user:~$ builtin cd mysubdir
user:~/mysubdir$ unset -f cd  # undefine function
```

Or with an alias:

```
user:~$ alias cd='echo Trying to cd to'
user:~$ cd mysubdir
Trying to cd to mysubdir
user:~$ builtin cd mysubdir
user:~/mysubdir$ unalias cd  # undefine alias
```

Using `builtin` is also a good way to define a `cd` function that does something *and* changes directory (since calling `cd` from it would just keep calling the function again in an endless recursion.)

For example:

```
user:~ $ cd () { echo "Changing directory to ${1-home}"; builtin cd "$@"; }
user:~ $ cd mysubdir
Changing directory to mysubdir
user:~/mysubdir $ cd
Changing directory to home
user:~ $ unset -f cd  # undefine function
```

Comment: +1 The examples are particularly illustrative here.

Comment: In the case of an alias, is there any difference between `builtin cd mysubdir` and `\cd mysubdir`?

Comment: @gerrit Only if there is a function named `cd`, in which case `\cd` would bypass the alias and run the function. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16506263/4518341

Answer (score 15):

In most instances, there is no difference (but see below).  The `cd` command is a built-in command in all shells.  It needs to be built-in<sup>1</sup> as an external command can not change the environment of the invoking shell, and changing the working directory constitutes a change in its environment.

The `bash` command `builtin` forces the shell to use the built-in version of a command, even though there may be a shell function, alias, or external command available with the same name.

In the case where there *is* e.g. a shell function with the name `cd`, then `builtin cd` would *not* call that.  *Using `builtin cd` bypasses any overloaded functionality that may have been added through a shell function or alias by the user.*

Example:

The `cd` built-in command may be overloaded by a function that updates the prompt:

```
cd() {
    builtin cd "$@" && PS1=$(__update_prompt)
}
```

where `__update_prompt` is some other user-supplied function that outputs a string.

The `builtin cd` in the function would not call the function recursively.  Using `builtin cd` in a shell where this function is active, would additionally not call the function.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are Unices with an external `cd` command (macOS, and, I believe, Solaris).  The purpose of that command, which *can't* change the working directory for a shell, is possibly to satisfy the POSIX standard, which lists `cd` as one of the external utilities that should be available (`cd` is not one of the "special builtin utilities").  It may also serve as a test to see whether changing work directory to a given directory *would be possible*.

Comment: FWIW, MacOS would also fall in the category of OSs with an external `cd` command.

Comment: @yoann Indeed it does.

Comment: Thank you - you've made my day with top notch, well researched,, footnoted pedantry.

Comment: **most** shells -- it's an external program for execlineb, but then it's [cd](https://skarnet.org/software/execline/cd.html) will then exec its remaining arguments