# 'jobs' shows a no longer existing process as running

Tags: bash, shell, job-control, jobs

I'm running a long-running pipeline from bash, in the background:

```
find / -size +500M -name '*.txt' -mtime +90 |
   xargs -n1 gzip -v9 &
```

The 2nd stage of the pipeline takes a long time to complete (hours) since there are several big+old files.

In contrast, the 1st part of the pipeline completes immediately, and since the pipe isn't full, and it has completed, `find` exits successfully.

The parent `bash` process seems to `wait` properly for child processes.

I can tell this because there's no `find` (pid 20851) running according to either:

```
     ps alx | grep 20851
     pgrep -l find
```

There's no zombie process, nor there's any process with process-id `20851` to be found anywhere on the system.

The bash builtin `jobs` correctly shows the job as a single line, without any process ids:

```
[1]+  Running find / -size +500M -name '*.txt' -mtime +90 | xargs -n1 gzip -v9 &
```

OTOH: I stumbled by accident on a separate job control command (`/bin/jobs`) which shows:

```
[1]+ 20851 Running         find / -size +500M -name '*.txt' -mtime +90
     20852 Running         | xargs -n1 gzip -v9 &
```

and which is (wrongly) showing the already exited `20851` find process as "Running".

This is on CentOS (edit: More accurately: `Amazon Linux 2 AMI`) Linux.
Turns out that `/bin/jobs` is a two line `/bin/sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
builtin jobs "$@"
```

This is surprising to me. How can a separate process, started from another program (`sh`), know the details of a process which is managed by another (`bash`) after that process has already completed and exited and is NOT a zombie?

Further:
how can it know details (including `pid`) about the already exited process, when other methods on the system (`ps`, `pgrep`) can't?

**Edits:**

(1) As Uncle Billy noted in the comments, on this system `/bin/sh` and`/bin/bash` are the same (`/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`) but `/bin/jobs` is a script with a shebang line so it runs in a separate process.

(2) Also, thanks to Uncle Billy: an easier way to reproduce. `/bin/jobs` was a red herring. I mistakenly assumed it is the one producing the output. The surprising output apparently came from the bash builtin `jobs` when called with `-l`:

```
$ sleep 1 | sleep 3600 &
[1] 13616
$ jobs -l
[1]+ 13615 Running                 sleep 1
     13616 Running                 | sleep 3600 &
$ ls /proc/13615
ls: cannot access /proc/13615: No such file or directory
```

So process 13615 doesn't exist, but is shown as "Running" by bash builtin job control, which appears like a bug in `jobs -l`.

The presence on `/bin/jobs` which confused me to think it must be the culprit (it wasn't), seems confusing and questionable.  I believe it should be removed from the system as it is useless (a `sh` script running in a separate process, which can't show jobs of the caller anyway).

Comment: The second (dubious) format is shown by `jobs -l`, even when a process has exited: `sleep 1 | sleep 3600 &` ... after 2 secs `jobs -l` will show both as running, though the first `sleep` has terminated. What version of bash is that? What does `alias | grep jobs` say?

Comment: @UncleBilly nice reproductions. 
`$ bash --version` shows `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-koji-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Sorry if that's not an answer, but it's impossible to format anything in comments. What does `type /bin/jobs` say? Notice that on centos/rhel `/bin/sh` is still bash under another name.

Comment: `$ type /bin/jobs` shows:
`/bin/jobs is /bin/jobs`
I have no alias for jobs, and indeed `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash` on this system, so same program, different processes. Great questions!

Comment: Of course another program cannot have access to its parent's memory (the jobs table in this case) after an `execve(2)`, as running `/bin/jobs` should be -- unless there's some kind of trick. Another possibility would be that either `jobs` or `builtin` is an exported function ;-)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I run a fresh Amazon Linux 2 in VirtualBox from a newly downloaded image. There is `/bin/jobs`, its content is what you wrote; but it behaves like we all expect, not like in the question. So if things work for you as you described then it's not because of the Amazon Linux 2 itself (phew!).

Comment: Sharing knowledge: `jobs` is specified by POSIX and [POSIX explicitly requires it as a standalone executable](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_06). In this matter Amazon Linux 2 is more POSIX-compliant than e.g. Debian. Note in AL2 there is [`/usr/bin/cd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38819/108618) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, I can reproduce your case with:

```
rhel8$ /bin/jobs(){ jobs -l; }
rhel8$ sleep 1 | sleep 3600 &
[1] 2611
rhel8$ sleep 2
rhel8$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 1 | sleep 3600 &
rhel8$ /bin/jobs
[1]+  2610 Running                 sleep 1
      2611 Running                 | sleep 3600 &
rhel8$ pgrep 2610
    <nothing!>
rhel8$ ls /proc/2610
ls: cannot access '/proc/2610': No such file or directory
rhel8$ /bin/jobs
[1]+  2610 Running                 sleep 1
      2611 Running                 | sleep 3600 &
rhel8$ cat /bin/jobs
#!/bin/sh
builtin jobs "$@"
```

Or with (even lamer than the previous):

```
rhel8$ unset -f /bin/jobs
rhel8$ export JOBS=$(jobs -l)
rhel8$ builtin(){ echo "$JOBS"; }
rhel8$ export -f builtin
rhel8$ /bin/jobs
[1]+  2610 Running                 sleep 1
      2611 Running                 | sleep 3600 &
rhel8$ type /bin/jobs
/bin/jobs is /bin/jobs
```

Note: As already demonstrated, `jobs -l` in bash is displaying stale information, with pipeline processes which have already exited still shown as `Running`. IMHO this is a bug -- other shells like zsh, ksh or yash correctly show them as `Done`.

Comment: Seems like the bigger bug is the very existence of `/bin/jobs` (which made me so confused). What is the purpose of `/bin/jobs` if it can't show any jobs in the caller anyway?

Comment: its only purpose is to fullfill some posix standard requirement -- but the only people who knew its original rationale have either died, gone mad or no longer remember it (to paraphrase Lord Palmerston