# Permissions denied in Kali Linux

Tags: permissions, sudo, kali-linux, cd-command, root-filesystem

I cannot get into /root and even when i use "sudo ls /root" it asks me for the password then nothing happens. Im new to linux and when I was testing out Kali linux i tried using permission commands like entering into /root but it did not accept. I tried using "sudo cd /root" but when i run this i get "sudo: cd: command not found". However when i check binaries in /bin the sudo command is there.

Comment: (1) "nothing happens" – If `/root` is empty, what do you expect? (2) [Why is `cd` not a program?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38808/108618) (3) "I'm new to Linux" – [Yeah…](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/108618)

Comment: It you're new to Linux then Kali is not the right distribution to try. Pick one of the more friendly distributions - Mint and Ubuntu are two that spring to mind

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo -s` and enter password to change user to root. Then you can `cd` to `/root`