# Why is "echo" so much faster than "touch"?

Tags: shell, command, echo

I'm trying to update the timestamp to the current time on all of the xml files in my directory (recursively).  I'm using Mac OSX 10.8.5.

On about 300,000 files, the following `echo` command takes **10 seconds**:

```
for file in `find . -name "*.xml"`; do echo >> $file; done
```

However, the following `touch` command takes **10 minutes**! :

```
for file in `find . -name "*.xml"`; do touch $file; done
```

Why is echo so much faster than touch here?

Comment: The answer could be in the source code of these binaries. Will have a look (if i can), but your flags are `linux` and `macosx`. What are your OS/version and FS type ?

Comment: Just a side remark: You _do_ know that those two commands are not equivalent, don't you? At least for Unix/Linux, the `echo >> $file` will append a newline to `$file` and thus modify it. I assume it will be the same for OS/X. If you do not want that, use `echo -n >> $file`.

Comment: Also wouldn't ``touch  `find . -name "*.xml"` `` be even faster than both of the above?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's faster, but simpler is `find . -name "*.xml" -execdir touch {} \;`

Comment: Or consider just `>>$file`

Comment: @Dubu `echo -n` is a valid builtin for bash on OS X and on 10.9.2 the timings for `/bin/echo` match the timings for `/bin/touch` with the shell builtin of `echo` orders of magnitude faster as expected/explained.

Comment: Not an answer to the explicit question, but why invoke `touch` so many times at all? `find . -name '*.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 touch` invokes `touch` much fewer times (possibly only once). Works on Linux, should work on OS X.

Comment: @elmo argument list too long (easily, with 300.000 files...)

Comment: @Rmano look at Mike's comment. Same principle, but overcomes issue you mention.

Comment: Mac OS X is POSIX compliant which I hope clarifies all these should's and dunnos. The question really is which shell and has been answered (default: bash).

Comment: @Dubu Please note that ``echo -n >> $file`` or even ``>> $file`` does not update timestamp. Well, at least on my system and bash.

Comment: @vaab Good catch, you are right.

Answer (score 164):

In bash, `touch` is an external binary, but `echo` is a [shell builtin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1359/10762):

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
$ type touch
touch is /usr/bin/touch
```

Since `touch` is an external binary, and you invoke `touch` once per file, the shell must create 300,000 instances of `touch`, which takes a long time.

`echo`, however, is a shell builtin, and the execution of shell builtins does not require forking at all. Instead, the current shell does all of the operations and no external processes are created; this is the reason why it is so much faster.

Here are two profiles of the shell's operations. You can see that a lot of time is spent cloning new processes when using `touch`. Using `/bin/echo` instead of the shell builtin should show a much more comparable result.

---

#### Using touch

```
$ strace -c -- bash -c 'for file in a{1..10000}; do touch "$file"; done'
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 56.20    0.030925           2     20000     10000 wait4
 38.12    0.020972           2     10000           clone
  4.67    0.002569           0     80006           rt_sigprocmask
  0.71    0.000388           0     20008           rt_sigaction
  0.27    0.000150           0     10000           rt_sigreturn
[...]
```

---

#### Using echo

```
$ strace -c -- bash -c 'for file in b{1..10000}; do echo >> "$file"; done'
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 34.32    0.000685           0     50000           fcntl
 22.14    0.000442           0     10000           write
 19.59    0.000391           0     10011           open
 14.58    0.000291           0     20000           dup2
  8.37    0.000167           0     20013           close
[...]
```

Comment: Did you compile strace on OS X or run your test on another OS?

Comment: @bmike My test is on Linux, but the principle is identical.

Comment: I totally agree - see my comment on the main question about how /bin/echo is as slow as /bin/touch so the reasoning is sound. I just wanted to reproduce the timing of strace and failed using dtruss/dtrace and the bash -c syntax doesn't work as expected on OS X either.

Answer (score 75):

As others have answered, using `echo` will be faster than `touch` as `echo` is a command which is commonly (though not required to be) built-in to the shell. Using it dispenses with the kernel overhead associated with running starting a new process for each file that you get with `touch`.

However, note that the fastest way to achieve this effect is still to use `touch`, but rather than running the program once for each file, it is possible to use the `-exec` option with `find` to ensure that is only run a few times. This approach will usually be faster since it avoids the overhead associated with a shell loop:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec touch {} +
```

Using the `+` (as opposed to `\;`) with `find ... -exec` runs the command only once if possible with each file as an argument. If the argument list is very long (as is the case with 300,000 files) multiple runs will be made with an argument list which has a length close to the limit (`ARG_MAX` on most systems).

Another advantage to this approach is that it behaves robustly with filenames containing all whitespace characters which is not the case with the original loop.

Comment: `+1` for pointing out the find `+` argument.  I think many people are not aware of this (I wasn't).

Comment: Not all versions of `find` have the `+` argument. You can get a similar effect by piping to `xargs`.

Comment: ...specifically, `find . -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 touch`.

Comment: @Barmar, the `+` part is required by POSIX, so should be portable. `-print0` isn't.

Comment: I still occasionally run into implementations that don't have it. YMMV.

Comment: @Graeme OpenBSD didn't have it for a long time, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @ChrisDown, Something I have discovered is that the Busybox `find` has the option available but just treats it like a `;` underneath the surface.

Comment: I wasn't aware that + could be used with the -exec option to find.  GREAT call, very educational, even for this sysadmin of 20 years!

Comment: @SplinterReality, it's only POSIX-standardized inside the last decade, so for most of your 20 years you weren't missing anything.

Answer (score 29):

`echo` is a shell builtin.  On the other hand, `touch` is an external binary.

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
$ type touch
touch is hashed (/usr/bin/touch)
```

[Shell builtins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin) are much faster as there is no overhead involved in loading the program, i.e. there is no `fork`/`exec` involved.  As such, you'd observe a significant time difference when executing a builtin vs an external command a large number of times.

This is the reason that utilities like `time` are available as shell builtins.

You can get the complete list of shell builtins by saying:

```
enable -p
```

---

As mentioned above, using the *utility* as opposed to the *builtin* results in a significant performance degradation.  Following are the statistics of the time taken to create ~9000 files using the *builtin* `echo` and the *utility* `echo`:

```
# Using builtin
$ time bash -c 'for i in {1000..9999}; do echo > $i; done'

real    0m0.283s
user    0m0.100s
sys 0m0.184s

# Using utility /bin/echo
$ time bash -c 'for i in {1000..9999}; do /bin/echo > $i; done'

real    0m8.683s
user    0m0.360s
sys 0m1.428s
```

Comment: And I think there's an `echo` binary on most systems (for me it's `/bin/echo`), so you can retry the timing tests using that instead of the built-in

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Added timing tests for the builtin and the binary.