# How to create multiple files with basic content - Parrot Linux

Tags: parrotsec

I wanted to know how I can create x number of files with content in a folder?

For example:

I want to create 250 files with basic content in my files test folder located in my home directory.

All I really need assistance on is how to create a lot of files with content for testing purpose using bash shell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can code a loop that creates a file with content and run it 250 times:

```
for i in $(seq 1 250) ; do echo -n "content" > ~/test/file$i ; done
```

Explanation:

- `seq 1 250`: show numbers from 1 to 250. It will be used by for to counts how much run you need.
- `echo -n "content" > ~/test/file$i`: save "content" to your files in your "test" folder located in your home directory.

I prefer use `echo -n > file$i` because is more fast than `touch file$1`:

```
>> time ./01.sh
./01.sh  0,03s user 0,06s system 28% cpu 0,316 total
>> time ./02.sh
./02.sh  0,01s user 0,00s system 77% cpu 0,017 total
```

**01.sh** content:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {001..250} ; do touch ./01/file$i ; done
```

**02.sh** content:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {001..250} ; do echo -n > ./02/file$i ; done
```

Comment: Here's an explanation of why echo is faster than touch: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123850/4721

Answer (score 1):

For start, you can begin with this simple bash for loop:

```
for i in {001..250} ; do touch ./file$i ; done
```

This will create 250 empty files in current directory, named file001 till file250.

Touch (in this case) just creates a file, if it does not exist. Empty file.
If you want to create files with something in them, you can change the `do` part of the `for` loop. For instance `do cp ./master.file ./newfile.$i` - which will copy file called master.file into the 250 new files and those will be called newfile.001 up to newfile.250.

Is it too confusing? It took me a while to understand how these things work in bash, but once I managed, I use it nearly every day. So feel free to ask, I'll try to explain it more and/or better.

Answer (score 0):

In complement to the previous (very good) answer, I will focus on
putting some content in the files -- in this case, 3 random English words and
a random number:

```
$ for a in {001..009}
do
(shuf -n 3 /usr/share/dict/words ; echo $RANDOM)  > FILE_$a
done
```

Example of generated file:

```
$ cat FILE_005
atrophy
grays
backdate
9612
```